# How to interact with a smart card in Java?

Tags: java, smartcard, smartcard-reader

Is there is a library (API) in Java with which I can interact with a smart card? Similar to the WinSCard library.

I need to be able to connect with the smart card and read data from it. I need to implement it in Java so that I can use it under any OS (Linux, Mac, Windows). Since, the WinSCard library only works under Windows because it uses a DLL (*WinSCard.dll*).

Is there anything as good as WinSCard in Java?

Answer (score 8):

One of the solutions is to use [Java™ Smart Card I/O API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/security/smartcardio/spec/index.html?javax/smartcardio/package-summary.html). See the ["Description"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/security/smartcardio/spec/javax/smartcardio/package-summary.html#package.description) section for a simple usage example.

Comment: +1. There is an API example at the end of that page which is really helpful.

Comment: how can you get this api ? im currently using jre7

Comment: @ralphspoon This API is available with a JDK installation (since Java version 6). So first, you need to have [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) installed ([What is the difference between JDK and JRE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906445/what-is-the-difference-between-jdk-and-jre)). Second, add related imports at the top of your Java file (or import everything, e.g. `import javax.smartcardio.*;`)

Answer (score 1):

The basic API is the [Smartcard IO](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/security/smartcardio/spec/javax/smartcardio/package-summary.html), which offer basic operation to send APDU to the card. After this, there is several higher API available. For instance, if you need to connect to a JavaCard to manage applet, you need a Global Platform implementation, for instance the [Opal Library](https://bitbucket.org/ssd/opal) (Shameless Self-promotion).

Answer (score 1):

PC/SC specification as a reader and a satandard interface between card and computer.Open the VC support PC/SC standard key header file WinScard.h.
With java can call the PC/SC of VC.As a middle way to solve you problems.