# Getting error "HTTP Status 404" -" The requested resource is not available" when running a web application?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, web-applications

I am using the eclipse helios and tomcat 7.0.33 to develope the web application . I am making use of "com.sysdeo.eclipse.tomcat_3.3.0" plugin with the eclise helios and have added the server(tomcat) using preferences to the eclipse.

Also I am successfully able to start and stop the tomcat server . I am using pre-installed jre as Java with the server.

But I am not able to successfully run the web applcation. I am also downloaded the zip example from the internet and imported in the eclipse , but was not able to successfully run it.

Is there any good links explaining how to use the Eclipse Helios and Tomcat 7.0.33 to develop the dynamic web applications and successfully run them???

Or what other could be the reason of this error????

Looking for Help!!!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I need JDK to work with Eclipse Helios and Tomcat 7.0.33?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13601478/do-i-need-jdk-to-work-with-eclipse-helios-and-tomcat-7-0-33)

Comment: You should answer the questions people are asking you on the exact same question you posted only a few minutes ago.

Comment: No its not the duplicate of that question..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, did you add the project to the Tomcat instance? Under the server view, if you expand(+) the listed Tomcat server is the project displayed underneath? If not, right click on the server and use the add/remove dialog.

If you've done all that, and the project is indeed added to Tomcat, are there any errors that appear when you try to run one of the JSPs? For example, if you selected your welcome page, right clicked and selected Run As --> Run on Server, do you see any errors?

EDIT: my apologies, I see you are stating you are seeing a 404 exception. Perhaps try to remove and re-add the project using the add/remove dialog. I know I've seen it get wonky sometimes and that may reset any configuration errors.

Here are some more details - hope they help:

So, Here is my empty Tomcat server (running) in my IDE.
[image: here is my empty tomcat in Eclipse]

To add my project, I right-click to view the context menu shown, and select Add and Remove.
[image: add and remove project to Tomcat in Eclipse IDE]

When I select Add and Remove, I see this dialog showing the projects that can be added. I select the project(s) to add, hit the add button and then finish.
[image: Add and Remove empty]

Once that is done, I see that my project(s) have been added to my tomcat instance.
[image]

Again, Tomcat may need a restart.

Comment: Thanks a lot Brian. I think I have not added it . I am using Eclipse Helios,Tomcat 7.0.33 and making use of "com.sysdeo.eclipse.tomcat_3.3.0" plugin(which I have copied in the plugin directory of the Eclipse before adding the Tomcat in eclipse) .Could you please guide me to add that?

Comment: Very sorry but Im not familiar with that plugin. In fact, I never had to explicitly get a plugin to run the integrated tomcat in eclipse. But, to be fair, I don't think I've used that version of Eclipse so you could be seeing behavior I'm not familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

oki.. Now I am adding the server from the starting again . I have removed all the previous things and the plugins .

Again starting from the

server tab-> Right Click on Server Tab( in the Bottom) -> New

->Server  and then Selected "Tomcat v7.0 Server" .

In the new server Environment, I am using  the following details

```
 Name :- Apache Tomcat v7.0 (3)

Tomcat Installation Directory :-C:\Documents and Settings\499451\My Documents\Tomcat_7\apache-tomcat-7.0.33,,,   JRE :- jre6(installed JRE)
```

and then I clicked on Finish Button.

Then on the Define a New Server Dialog I am using the details

Server's Host Name :- localhost

Server Name        :- Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost

Server runtime Environment :- Apache Tomcat v7.0

Then I clicked on the finish button and the added tomcat server is now shown in the window under Server Tab.

But when I typed the URL : "http://localhost:8080/"

### Then I am getting the following error :

HTTP Status 404 -/

type :- Status report

message :-/

### description :-The requested resource is not available.

What could be the reason of this error?

Looking for Help!

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but maybe I could help someone who lands here.

In case you are unable to get your tomcat up and running, you should double click on the created server in the servers tab in eclipse. A new tab would open inside eclipse. There, under Server locations, select the middle option, "Use Tomcat Installation". Then hit https://localhost:8080/. It should work

Please note that if you already have added a war file, you should remove it before you try the above suggestion.

Hope it helps.