# problems compiling with javac and java

Tags: java, environment-variables, javac

This problem is a bit embarrassing, and the solution is most likely on your web site somewhere, but I haven't been able to find it, so here goes:  I've just installed Java to my C:\ drive, and while the machine can find java it can't find javac, to wit:

```
C:\>java -version
java version "1.7.0_11"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_11-b21)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.6-b04, mixed mode)


C:\>javac -version
Error: Could not find or load main class com.sun.tools.javac.Main
```

and I get the above response even when I'm sitting IN the bin directory.  I'm stumped.

I've tried updating both the PATH and JAVA_HOME environment variables, and I'm sorta stuck.  Can anyone help?  Note: I'm glad to go to the appropriate spot on your site, but I haven't been able to locate it, if you just point me to it I will consider myself helped, and thanks.

Comment: Tried re-installing jdk?

Comment: http://www.sachinmore.com/2008/01/unable-to-load-default-compiler-class.html

Comment: cd to your `JAVA_HOME` dir. cd into the `lib` dir within `JAVA_HOME`. Verify that you have `tools.jar` in the `$JAVA_HOME/lib` dir. Is it there?

Comment: Good answer, Alderath, that seems to be my trouble.  When I looked in the JAVA_HOME\lib directory there was NO tools.jar.  So, I guess I'll just take Aniket's advice and reinstall the JDK.  Thanks to everyone who helped solve this mystery.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be because you might have installed JRE, so you are able to use java command

`javac` command is used compiling java programs, hence its for development

And for development you need to install JDK

Have a look at this :

[What is the difference between JDK and JRE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906445/what-is-the-difference-between-jdk-and-jre)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  No, it's a JDK, in fact it is jdk-7u11-windows-x64, which is correct for this machine.  Must be something else.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the environment variable i.e. path.
If you are using Windows 7, then Right click on my computer -> change settings -> advanced -> environment variable -> change path to bin folder of java (`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin`), 
no need to earse the prev path in path variable. Just give ";" at end, paste the link of the JDK's bin folder, and type ";".

Comment: Thanks for your answer as well.  I think I did specify the correct environment variable, at least when I type echo %PATH% what get reported back is