# Javac not working

Tags: javac

I am new to Java Packaging, I am trying to compile Java code and wanted below 2 things

- java compiles code and places .java file in src folder
- java compiles code and places .class file in .com folder

so I tried below command

```
javac -s .\src -d .\com Planet.java
```

The command runs successfully without any error; the class files are placed in the com folder but the source files are still not moved to the src folder. I have created the folders com and src manually in the current folder. Planet.java is also in the current folder.

```
├───com  
│   └───test  
└───src
```

Am I missing any tricks here? Please correct me.

Answer (score 0):

The javac command will not actually move your source files. The `-s` option in javac is for telling javac where to place generated source files, not for moving yours.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html

Comment: But still no files generated in src folder, any Idea?

Comment: Just did verbose and didn't found any thin related to -s   >javac -verbose -s .\src -d .\com Planet.java
[parsing started Planet.java]
[parsing completed 14ms]
[search path for source files:.....
[loading java\lang\Enum.class(java\lang:Enum.class)]
[loading java\lang\Comparable.class(java\lang:Comparable.class)]
[loading java\lang\Object.class(java\lang:Object.class)]
[loading java\io\Serializable.class(java\io:Serializable.class)]
[loading java\lang\String.class(java\lang:String.class)]
[checking test.Planet]

Comment: [loading java\lang\CloneNotSupportedException.class(java\lang:CloneNotSupportedException.class)]
[loading java\lang\Class.class(java\lang:Class.class)]
[loading java\lang\System.class(java\lang:System.class)]
[loading java\io\PrintStream.class(java\io:PrintStream.class)]
[loading java\io\FilterOutputStream.class(java\io:FilterOutputStream.class)]
[loading java\io\OutputStream.class(java\io:OutputStream.class)]
[loading java\lang\Double.class(java\lang:Double.class)][loading java\lang\Number.class(java\lang:Number.class)]
[loading java\util\Locale.class(java\util:Locale.class)]

Comment: [loading java\lang\Error.class(java\lang:Error.class)]
[loading java\lang\NumberFormatException.class(java\lang:NumberFormatException.class)]
[loading java\lang\IllegalArgumentException.class(java\lang:IllegalArgumentException.class)]
[loading java\lang\RuntimeException.class(java\lang:RuntimeException.class)]
[loading java\lang\Exception.class(java\lang:Exception.class)]
[loading java\lang\Throwable.class(java\lang:Throwable.class)]
[loading java\lang\Byte.class(java\lang:Byte.class)]
[loading java\lang\Character.class(java\lang:Character.class)]

Comment: [loading java\lang\Integer.class(java\lang:Integer.class)]
[loading java\lang\Long.class(java\lang:Long.class)]
[loading java\lang\Float.class(java\lang:Float.class)]
[loading java\lang\Boolean.class(java\lang:Boolean.class)]
[loading java\lang\Void.class(java\lang:Void.class)]
[wrote .\com\test\Planet.class]
[total 256ms]   after this nothing, please let me know if any settings ned to be changed

Comment: To clarify: AFAIK you are not *generating* new source files, only *compiling* the exisiting `Planet.java`.  Generated source code is created programmatically by other code, not written by you.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't post full stacktraces into the comments: add them to your question instead.

Comment: Anyone found the solution? cos my javac is not returning me my class

Answer (score 0):

In order to use [`javac`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) in `cmd`, JDK (Java Development Kit) must be installed on your system.

`javac.exe` is inside JDK's `bin` folder (e.g.: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin`), and **NOT** in JRE's bin folder (`C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin`), because JRE is just a runtime environment (but you need the development kit to be able to compile source code).

You should append JDK's bin directory (`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin`) to the PATH system environment variable.

If you don't have JDK, please download it from the following link:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

Reference thread for JDK vs. JRE:
[What is the difference between JDK and JRE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906445/what-is-the-difference-between-jdk-and-jre)

**Procedure:**

1. Install JDK
2. open command prompt
3. type **"`cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin`"**, press Enter (path may change based on JDK version and 32-bit/64-bit OS version)
4. type **"`javac`"**, press Enter

Done.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question at all.