# Java Split() Method not being identified

Tags: java

I've got to use the method `split()` as in the following code, but the compiler throws an error:

```
String defA1[] = new str1.split(" ");
```

The error thrown says:

```
error: package str1 does not exist
       String defA2[] = new str1.split(" ");
                                ^
```

Obviously it is not a package, `str1` is a string previously defined that comes as an argument of a method, as following:

```
public static int calculateLevenshteinDistance(String str1, String str2) { ... }
```

I am also importing the package `java.lang`

```
import java.lang.*;
```

and even explicitly

```
import java.lang.String;
```

Please do not suggest `StringTokenizer`, I want to know why this is not working.

Also you could help me with something else. I tried importing the package as static just wondering if that could fix it:

```
import static java.lang.*;
```

But the compiler would say:

```
error: cannot find symbol
            import static java.lang.*;
                              ^
```

It only happens when I add "static" to the import and it happens with any static import I dont know why.

I am using the JVM to compile.

Comment: What's the `new` doing in there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. You should just use `String defA1[] =  str1.split(" ");`. The `new` keyword is meant to call a class constructor and create a new instance of the class. More info: [Oracle Java Tutorial: Creating Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)

By the way, Java compiler already adds `import java.lang.*` by you, no need to add a `static` import to this package.

One more note, the JVM (the JRE) is not meant to compile the code, just to run it. You compile Java code using the Java SDK. More info: [What is the difference between JDK and JRE?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1906445/1065197)

Additional: If you want to know why the compiler gives you the message error *package str1 does not exist*

The compiler is trying to read this line

```
new str1.split(" ");
```

as *Create a new instance of the class `split` that is inside the `str1` package and send a `String` parameter to the constructor with value `" "`.* This is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
String defA1[] = str1.split(" ");
```

No need of new operator

Answer (score 1):

It should be :

```
String defA2[] = str1.split(" ");
```