# javac cannot be run, and furthermore does not seem installed

Tags: java, javac

I have a problem involving setting up Java.

I have installed the JRE, added its path to `PATH`, and set `JAVA_HOME` and `CLASSPATH`. Now, `java` and `javacpl` work fine, but running `javac` generates a command-not-found error. Furthermore, `javac.exe` does not even seem to exist in the JRE's `bin` folder.

How do I run `javac`?

Answer (score 25):

The JRE is merely the **Java Runtime Environment**, which includes only the infrastructure needed to run Java programs that are already compiled.

To compile Java source code using `javac`, you need the **Java Development Kit** (JDK).

On Oracle's [Java download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html), choose the package labelled "JDK".

Comment: That's strange. I don't remember having any problems with compiling code with a stock installation of older Java versions (not that I needed this too often).

Answer (score 6):

In order to use javac in cmd , JDK must be installed in your system...

javac will not work if you are pointing "bin" folder  inside JRE (C:\Program Files\Java**jre7**\bin)

Please check for javac.exe inside your bin folder(C:\Program Files\Java**jdk1.7.0_45**\bin)

javac.exe must be inside **JDK**(C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin) not inside **JRE** (C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin)  **"JRE doesn't come with a compiler. It is simply a java runtime environment. What you need is the developmental kit."** in order to use  compiler javac

**For javac  path**(Points to remember while setting system env variable)

*path = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin*  **this is wrong**

*path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin*  **this is correct**

Make sure "javac.exe" must be inside your **"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin"**

Dont confuse with JRE and JDK  both are totally different

if you dont have JDK pls download from this link http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

reference thread for JDK VS JRE  [What is the difference between JDK and JRE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906445/what-is-the-difference-between-jdk-and-jre)

**Procedure:-**

1. Install JDK
2. open cmd prompt
3. type **"cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin "** press enter(path may change based on jdk version and 32bit and 64bit os version)
4. type **"javac"** press enter

its done

Now go and change your system environment variable
 **path = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin**

this will set the path permanently

Answer (score 0):

The JRE doesn't have javac - you need to download the JDK (Java Development Kit).

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to install the jdk, then add the path of bin folder of jdk in the path vaiable.

you can refer to this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install)