# is jre sufficient to run googlemap in android app without having jdk installed

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I use eclipse only under jre, and I want to display a map from google, is there possible to follow all steps using jre not jdk

Answer (score 0):

You will have to install JDK for displaying Google Maps in your App.
There is a brief discussion on the difference between JDK and JRE, you can take a reference to that:
[What is the difference between JDK and JRE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906445/what-is-the-difference-between-jdk-and-jre)
I hope this helps.

Comment: but eclipse does not recognize GoogleMap even if I followed all steps

Comment: no. jdk includes things like, hum, javac, which is not in the jre (obviously)