# Android Studio: Need a java compiler

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting an error while trying to run an android application. I am running android studio 0.3.2 on Windows 8 64-bit.

Here's the error

```
java: System Java Compiler was not found in classpath:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.javac.JavacMain.compile(JavacMain.java:79)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compileJava(JavaBuilder.java:375)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compile(JavaBuilder.java:278)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.doBuild(JavaBuilder.java:190)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:162)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1087)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:798)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:846)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:761)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:582)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:343)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:183)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:129)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:224)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:113)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$1.run(BuildMain.java:133)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$1.run(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:41)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Help appreciated!

Comment: How about installing a java compiler?

Comment: Yeah, you should have a JDK installed (preferably 64-bit as your OS is 64-bit) and set the JAVA_HOME path variable to that location.

Answer (score 0):

As people suggested in comments, you should install JDK.
To maintain the difference, refer to: [What is the difference between JDK and JRE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906445/what-is-the-difference-between-jdk-and-jre).

There are a lot of guides on the internet but the easiest way to install JDK is to visit [Oracle Downloads page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and install the required one.

After installing read [official guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/) how to set up environment.
Also, this question is answered in SO: [How to set JAVA_HOME on Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7)

After this, Intellij IDEA (Android Studio) will fetch JDK automatically.
If not, go to `Project Structure` and set up JDK path manually:
[image]