# Project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to build a Java project. This used to be a breeze for me but ever since I changed my workspace to another location to store my new projects, I've been running into trouble. I get these two errors.

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved    InterviewPractice       Unknown Java Problem
Unbound classpath container: 'JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.7]' in project 'InterviewPractice'   InterviewPractice       Build path  Build Path Problem
```

I've looked up fixes online but none of them seem to be working for me.

While building the project, selecting the JRE selection. I'm also not sure what to choose. I think default it was set to `OSGi/minimum 1.0` but I'm honestly not sure what that does. I simply want to build simple programs for interview practice. So `JavaSE-1.7`?

when I click JRE system library a popup that says An error has occurred. See error log for more details. java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: right click on the project --> `properties` --> `Java build path` and tell us if there are an y issues there.

Comment: I see an icon with a red x for JRE system library[JavaSE-1.7](unbound)

Comment: C? I have a Mac. I dont think this applies unless there is something I am missing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is about your jre version. Did you try jre6 ?

Package Explorer >> Right Click >> Build Patch >> Configure Build Path >> Libraries >>

Delete Your JRE .

Then Add Library >> JRE System Library >> Environments >> Select JRE6 >> Finish

Comment: ALl i see under libraries is `default system library (unbound)`

Comment: Also when I click JRE system library a popup that says `An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: You have to download JRE6 or JRE7 and you have to set home_path ! This link usefull for you : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-install-faq.html

Comment: okay im downloading it now ill will update you once its done. Thanks!

Comment: When did you download you have to set home path and make my answer list. Then you have to clean and build your project.

Comment: I downloaded JDK because according to this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906445/what-is-the-difference-between-jdk-and-jre) JRE is in JDK and I'll need JDK for other project but I am having the same problems.. no fixes =/

Comment: This worked for my current workspace. However when I switch workspaces, the second one will have the same errors...

Comment: Build Path issue. When you change your workspace your eclipse conf change also.

Comment: I think i seem to be understanding what you mean now. When I change workspaces, the JRE isnt there.

Comment: I went into eclipse >> preferences >> installed JRE and nothing is in there and I see this warning on top `The selected JRE does not support the current compiler compliance level of 1.7`

Comment: I told you first you have to install JRE on your MAC. And set home_path http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-install-faq.html

Comment: I have this in my `.bash_profile` `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)` and it still isnt working =/