# when an instance of the JVM is instantiated?

Tags: java, jvm

I have a java class that contains an instruction to do something in a hosting platform.

```
java Foo.class
```

I believe that an instance of the JVM is created/instantiated after running "java" command. Did I understand it right? "java" command is an independent program or a process, but an instantiated JVM  is another process...

Comment: The `java` binary is the JVM. That is, unless your path is set up strangely, and it's actually pointing to some other script/binary.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/26025656/3448419 for the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

java (java.exe in Windows) is an application, it is a wrapper over jvm library (jvm.dll in Windows). We can say java.exe is a JVM launcher.

Answer (score 1):

The term "java command" is a little misleading. What you're launching is a program or application. In unix/linux that's a binary with the execute bit set, in windows it's a file with an *.exe extension, in OSX it could be a binary or an *.app

In all those cases what's happening is the OS launches a process called "java" that **is** the JVM.