# How to use objdump to disassemble OpenJDK(bin/java)?

Tags: java, c++, garbage-collection, disassembly, jvm-hotspot

I'd like to trace the user-level behavior of Java so I use uprobe.

In the example of [Tracing userspace using uprobe](https://opensource.com/article/17/7/dynamic-tracing-linux-user-and-kernel-space)

```
# gcc -o test test.c
# objdump -d test
```

OpenJDK is also a C++ program. But when I use objdump to java, it shows

```
wxf@wxf:/home/wxf/sandboxJDK/9jdk/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-slowdebug/jdk/bin$ objdump -d java

java:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .init:

00000000000009b0 <_init>:
 9b0:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
 9b4:   48 8b 05 2d 16 20 00    mov    0x20162d(%rip),%rax        # 201fe8 <__gmon_start__>
 9bb:   48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
 9be:   74 02                   je     9c2 <_init+0x12>
 9c0:   ff d0                   callq  *%rax
 9c2:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
 9c6:   c3                      retq   

Disassembly of section .plt:

00000000000009d0 <.plt>:
 9d0:   ff 35 9a 15 20 00       pushq  0x20159a(%rip)        # 201f70 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x8>
 9d6:   ff 25 9c 15 20 00       jmpq   *0x20159c(%rip)        # 201f78 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x10>
 9dc:   0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)

00000000000009e0 <JLI_InitArgProcessing@plt>:
 9e0:   ff 25 9a 15 20 00       jmpq   *0x20159a(%rip)        # 201f80 <JLI_InitArgProcessing@SUNWprivate_1.1>
 9e6:   68 00 00 00 00          pushq  $0x0
 9eb:   e9 e0 ff ff ff          jmpq   9d0 <.plt>

00000000000009f0 <getenv@plt>:
 9f0:   ff 25 92 15 20 00       jmpq   *0x201592(%rip)        # 201f88 <getenv@GLIBC_2.2.5>
 9f6:   68 01 00 00 00          pushq  $0x1
 9fb:   e9 d0 ff ff ff          jmpq   9d0 <.plt>

0000000000000a00 <JLI_PreprocessArg@plt>:
 a00:   ff 25 8a 15 20 00       jmpq   *0x20158a(%rip)        # 201f90 <JLI_PreprocessArg@SUNWprivate_1.1>
 a06:   68 02 00 00 00          pushq  $0x2
 a0b:   e9 c0 ff ff ff          jmpq   9d0 <.plt>

0000000000000a10 <JLI_List_new@plt>:
 a10:   ff 25 82 15 20 00       jmpq   *0x201582(%rip)        # 201f98 <JLI_List_new@SUNWprivate_1.1>
 a16:   68 03 00 00 00          pushq  $0x3
 a1b:   e9 b0 ff ff ff          jmpq   9d0 <.plt>

0000000000000a20 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>:
 a20:   ff 25 7a 15 20 00       jmpq   *0x20157a(%rip)        # 201fa0 <__stack_chk_fail@GLIBC_2.4>
 a26:   68 04 00 00 00          pushq  $0x4
 a2b:   e9 a0 ff ff ff          jmpq   9d0 <.plt>

0000000000000a30 <JLI_AddArgsFromEnvVar@plt>:
 a30:   ff 25 72 15 20 00       jmpq   *0x201572(%rip)        # 201fa8 <JLI_AddArgsFromEnvVar@SUNWprivate_1.1>
 a36:   68 05 00 00 00          pushq  $0x5
 a3b:   e9 90 ff ff ff          jmpq   9d0 <.plt>

0000000000000a40 <JLI_StringDup@plt>:
 a40:   ff 25 6a 15 20 00       jmpq   *0x20156a(%rip)        # 201fb0 <JLI_StringDup@SUNWprivate_1.1>
 a46:   68 06 00 00 00          pushq  $0x6
 a4b:   e9 80 ff ff ff          jmpq   9d0 <.plt>

0000000000000a50 <JLI_Launch@plt>:
 a50:   ff 25 62 15 20 00       jmpq   *0x201562(%rip)        # 201fb8 <JLI_Launch@SUNWprivate_1.1>
 a56:   68 07 00 00 00          pushq  $0x7
 a5b:   e9 70 ff ff ff          jmpq   9d0 <.plt>

0000000000000a60 <JLI_List_add@plt>:
 a60:   ff 25 5a 15 20 00       jmpq   *0x20155a(%rip)        # 201fc0 <JLI_List_add@SUNWprivate_1.1>
 a66:   68 08 00 00 00          pushq  $0x8
 a6b:   e9 60 ff ff ff          jmpq   9d0 <.plt>

0000000000000a70 <JLI_MemFree@plt>:
 a70:   ff 25 52 15 20 00       jmpq   *0x201552(%rip)        # 201fc8 <JLI_MemFree@SUNWprivate_1.1>
 a76:   68 09 00 00 00          pushq  $0x9
 a7b:   e9 50 ff ff ff          jmpq   9d0 <.plt>

0000000000000a80 <JLI_ReportMessage@plt>:
 a80:   ff 25 4a 15 20 00       jmpq   *0x20154a(%rip)        # 201fd0 <JLI_ReportMessage@SUNWprivate_1.1>
 a86:   68 0a 00 00 00          pushq  $0xa
 a8b:   e9 40 ff ff ff          jmpq   9d0 <.plt>

Disassembly of section .plt.got:

0000000000000a90 <__cxa_finalize@plt>:
 a90:   ff 25 62 15 20 00       jmpq   *0x201562(%rip)        # 201ff8 <__cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.2.5>
 a96:   66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000aa0 <_start>:
 aa0:   31 ed                   xor    %ebp,%ebp
 aa2:   49 89 d1                mov    %rdx,%r9
 aa5:   5e                      pop    %rsi
 aa6:   48 89 e2                mov    %rsp,%rdx
 aa9:   48 83 e4 f0             and    $0xfffffffffffffff0,%rsp
 aad:   50                      push   %rax
 aae:   54                      push   %rsp
 aaf:   4c 8d 05 da 03 00 00    lea    0x3da(%rip),%r8        # e90 <__libc_csu_fini>
 ab6:   48 8d 0d 63 03 00 00    lea    0x363(%rip),%rcx        # e20 <__libc_csu_init>
 abd:   48 8d 3d e6 00 00 00    lea    0xe6(%rip),%rdi        # baa <main>
 ac4:   ff 15 16 15 20 00       callq  *0x201516(%rip)        # 201fe0 <__libc_start_main@GLIBC_2.2.5>
 aca:   f4                      hlt    
 acb:   0f 1f 44 00 00          nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)

0000000000000ad0 <deregister_tm_clones>:
 ad0:   48 8d 3d 99 15 20 00    lea    0x201599(%rip),%rdi        # 202070 <__TMC_END__>
 ad7:   55                      push   %rbp
 ad8:   48 8d 05 91 15 20 00    lea    0x201591(%rip),%rax        # 202070 <__TMC_END__>
 adf:   48 39 f8                cmp    %rdi,%rax
 ae2:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 ae5:   74 19                   je     b00 <deregister_tm_clones+0x30>
 ae7:   48 8b 05 ea 14 20 00    mov    0x2014ea(%rip),%rax        # 201fd8 <_ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable>
 aee:   48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
 af1:   74 0d                   je     b00 <deregister_tm_clones+0x30>
 af3:   5d                      pop    %rbp
 af4:   ff e0                   jmpq   *%rax
 af6:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
 afd:   00 00 00 
 b00:   5d                      pop    %rbp
 b01:   c3                      retq   
 b02:   0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)
 b06:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
 b0d:   00 00 00 

0000000000000b10 <register_tm_clones>:
 b10:   48 8d 3d 59 15 20 00    lea    0x201559(%rip),%rdi        # 202070 <__TMC_END__>
 b17:   48 8d 35 52 15 20 00    lea    0x201552(%rip),%rsi        # 202070 <__TMC_END__>
 b1e:   55                      push   %rbp
 b1f:   48 29 fe                sub    %rdi,%rsi
 b22:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 b25:   48 c1 fe 03             sar    $0x3,%rsi
 b29:   48 89 f0                mov    %rsi,%rax
 b2c:   48 c1 e8 3f             shr    $0x3f,%rax
 b30:   48 01 c6                add    %rax,%rsi
 b33:   48 d1 fe                sar    %rsi
 b36:   74 18                   je     b50 <register_tm_clones+0x40>
 b38:   48 8b 05 b1 14 20 00    mov    0x2014b1(%rip),%rax        # 201ff0 <_ITM_registerTMCloneTable>
 b3f:   48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
 b42:   74 0c                   je     b50 <register_tm_clones+0x40>
 b44:   5d                      pop    %rbp
 b45:   ff e0                   jmpq   *%rax
 b47:   66 0f 1f 84 00 00 00    nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
 b4e:   00 00 
 b50:   5d                      pop    %rbp
 b51:   c3                      retq   
 b52:   0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)
 b56:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
 b5d:   00 00 00 

0000000000000b60 <__do_global_dtors_aux>:
 b60:   80 3d 09 15 20 00 00    cmpb   $0x0,0x201509(%rip)        # 202070 <__TMC_END__>
 b67:   75 2f                   jne    b98 <__do_global_dtors_aux+0x38>
 b69:   48 83 3d 87 14 20 00    cmpq   $0x0,0x201487(%rip)        # 201ff8 <__cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.2.5>
 b70:   00 
 b71:   55                      push   %rbp
 b72:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 b75:   74 0c                   je     b83 <__do_global_dtors_aux+0x23>
 b77:   48 8b 3d 8a 14 20 00    mov    0x20148a(%rip),%rdi        # 202008 <__dso_handle>
 b7e:   e8 0d ff ff ff          callq  a90 <__cxa_finalize@plt>
 b83:   e8 48 ff ff ff          callq  ad0 <deregister_tm_clones>
 b88:   c6 05 e1 14 20 00 01    movb   $0x1,0x2014e1(%rip)        # 202070 <__TMC_END__>
 b8f:   5d                      pop    %rbp
 b90:   c3                      retq   
 b91:   0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax)
 b98:   f3 c3                   repz retq 
 b9a:   66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)

0000000000000ba0 <frame_dummy>:
 ba0:   55                      push   %rbp
 ba1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 ba4:   5d                      pop    %rbp
 ba5:   e9 66 ff ff ff          jmpq   b10 <register_tm_clones>

0000000000000baa <main>:
 baa:   55                      push   %rbp
 bab:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
 bae:   48 83 ec 50             sub    $0x50,%rsp
 bb2:   89 7d bc                mov    %edi,-0x44(%rbp)
 bb5:   48 89 75 b0             mov    %rsi,-0x50(%rbp)
 bb9:   64 48 8b 04 25 28 00    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
 bc0:   00 00 
 bc2:   48 89 45 f8             mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
 bc6:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
 bc8:   c6 45 c7 00             movb   $0x0,-0x39(%rbp)
 bcc:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 bd1:   0f b6 c0                movzbl %al,%eax
 bd4:   89 c6                   mov    %eax,%esi
 bd6:   bf 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edi
 bdb:   e8 00 fe ff ff          callq  9e0 <JLI_InitArgProcessing@plt>
 be0:   8b 45 bc                mov    -0x44(%rbp),%eax
 be3:   83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
 be6:   48 98                   cltq   
 be8:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
 beb:   e8 20 fe ff ff          callq  a10 <JLI_List_new@plt>
 bf0:   48 89 45 d8             mov    %rax,-0x28(%rbp)
 bf4:   c7 45 c8 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x38(%rbp)
 bfb:   48 8b 45 b0             mov    -0x50(%rbp),%rax
 bff:   48 8b 00                mov    (%rax),%rax
 c02:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
 c05:   e8 36 fe ff ff          callq  a40 <JLI_StringDup@plt>
 c0a:   48 89 c2                mov    %rax,%rdx
 c0d:   48 8b 45 d8             mov    -0x28(%rbp),%rax
 c11:   48 89 d6                mov    %rdx,%rsi
 c14:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
 c17:   e8 44 fe ff ff          callq  a60 <JLI_List_add@plt>
 c1c:   48 8b 45 d8             mov    -0x28(%rbp),%rax
 c20:   48 8d 35 bf 02 00 00    lea    0x2bf(%rip),%rsi        # ee6 <const_disable_argfile+0x1>
 c27:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
 c2a:   e8 01 fe ff ff          callq  a30 <JLI_AddArgsFromEnvVar@plt>
 c2f:   84 c0                   test   %al,%al
 c31:   74 47                   je     c7a <main+0xd0>
 c33:   48 8d 3d bd 02 00 00    lea    0x2bd(%rip),%rdi        # ef7 <const_disable_argfile+0x12>
 c3a:   e8 b1 fd ff ff          callq  9f0 <getenv@plt>
 c3f:   48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
 c42:   74 36                   je     c7a <main+0xd0>
 c44:   48 8d 3d c1 02 00 00    lea    0x2c1(%rip),%rdi        # f0c <const_disable_argfile+0x27>
 c4b:   e8 a0 fd ff ff          callq  9f0 <getenv@plt>
 c50:   48 89 45 e0             mov    %rax,-0x20(%rbp)
 c54:   48 83 7d e0 00          cmpq   $0x0,-0x20(%rbp)
 c59:   74 1f                   je     c7a <main+0xd0>
 c5b:   48 8b 45 e0             mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
 c5f:   48 89 c2                mov    %rax,%rdx
 c62:   48 8d 35 a3 02 00 00    lea    0x2a3(%rip),%rsi        # f0c <const_disable_argfile+0x27>
 c69:   48 8d 3d aa 02 00 00    lea    0x2aa(%rip),%rdi        # f1a <const_disable_argfile+0x35>
 c70:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
 c75:   e8 06 fe ff ff          callq  a80 <JLI_ReportMessage@plt>
 c7a:   c7 45 c8 01 00 00 00    movl   $0x1,-0x38(%rbp)
 c81:   e9 c2 00 00 00          jmpq   d48 <main+0x19e>
 c86:   8b 45 c8                mov    -0x38(%rbp),%eax
 c89:   48 98                   cltq   
 c8b:   48 8d 14 c5 00 00 00    lea    0x0(,%rax,8),%rdx
 c92:   00 
 c93:   48 8b 45 b0             mov    -0x50(%rbp),%rax
 c97:   48 01 d0                add    %rdx,%rax
 c9a:   48 8b 00                mov    (%rax),%rax
 c9d:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
 ca0:   e8 5b fd ff ff          callq  a00 <JLI_PreprocessArg@plt>
 ca5:   48 89 45 f0             mov    %rax,-0x10(%rbp)
 ca9:   48 83 7d f0 00          cmpq   $0x0,-0x10(%rbp)
 cae:   75 33                   jne    ce3 <main+0x139>
 cb0:   8b 45 c8                mov    -0x38(%rbp),%eax
 cb3:   48 98                   cltq   
 cb5:   48 8d 14 c5 00 00 00    lea    0x0(,%rax,8),%rdx
 cbc:   00 
 cbd:   48 8b 45 b0             mov    -0x50(%rbp),%rax
 cc1:   48 01 d0                add    %rdx,%rax
 cc4:   48 8b 00                mov    (%rax),%rax
 cc7:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
 cca:   e8 71 fd ff ff          callq  a40 <JLI_StringDup@plt>
 ccf:   48 89 c2                mov    %rax,%rdx
 cd2:   48 8b 45 d8             mov    -0x28(%rbp),%rax
 cd6:   48 89 d6                mov    %rdx,%rsi
 cd9:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
 cdc:   e8 7f fd ff ff          callq  a60 <JLI_List_add@plt>
 ce1:   eb 61                   jmp    d44 <main+0x19a>
 ce3:   48 8b 45 f0             mov    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
 ce7:   48 8b 40 08             mov    0x8(%rax),%rax
 ceb:   89 45 d4                mov    %eax,-0x2c(%rbp)
 cee:   c7 45 cc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x34(%rbp)
 cf5:   eb 2a                   jmp    d21 <main+0x177>
 cf7:   48 8b 45 f0             mov    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
 cfb:   48 8b 00                mov    (%rax),%rax
 cfe:   8b 55 cc                mov    -0x34(%rbp),%edx
 d01:   48 63 d2                movslq %edx,%rdx
 d04:   48 c1 e2 03             shl    $0x3,%rdx
 d08:   48 01 d0                add    %rdx,%rax
 d0b:   48 8b 10                mov    (%rax),%rdx
 d0e:   48 8b 45 d8             mov    -0x28(%rbp),%rax
 d12:   48 89 d6                mov    %rdx,%rsi
 d15:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
 d18:   e8 43 fd ff ff          callq  a60 <JLI_List_add@plt>
 d1d:   83 45 cc 01             addl   $0x1,-0x34(%rbp)
 d21:   8b 45 cc                mov    -0x34(%rbp),%eax
 d24:   3b 45 d4                cmp    -0x2c(%rbp),%eax
 d27:   7c ce                   jl     cf7 <main+0x14d>
 d29:   48 8b 45 f0             mov    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
 d2d:   48 8b 00                mov    (%rax),%rax
 d30:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
 d33:   e8 38 fd ff ff          callq  a70 <JLI_MemFree@plt>
 d38:   48 8b 45 f0             mov    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
 d3c:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
 d3f:   e8 2c fd ff ff          callq  a70 <JLI_MemFree@plt>
 d44:   83 45 c8 01             addl   $0x1,-0x38(%rbp)
 d48:   8b 45 c8                mov    -0x38(%rbp),%eax
 d4b:   3b 45 bc                cmp    -0x44(%rbp),%eax
 d4e:   0f 8c 32 ff ff ff       jl     c86 <main+0xdc>
 d54:   48 8b 45 d8             mov    -0x28(%rbp),%rax
 d58:   48 8b 40 08             mov    0x8(%rax),%rax
 d5c:   89 45 d0                mov    %eax,-0x30(%rbp)
 d5f:   48 8b 45 d8             mov    -0x28(%rbp),%rax
 d63:   be 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%esi
 d68:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
 d6b:   e8 f0 fc ff ff          callq  a60 <JLI_List_add@plt>
 d70:   48 8b 45 d8             mov    -0x28(%rbp),%rax
 d74:   48 8b 00                mov    (%rax),%rax
 d77:   48 89 45 e8             mov    %rax,-0x18(%rbp)
 d7b:   44 0f b6 4d c7          movzbl -0x39(%rbp),%r9d
 d80:   b8 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%eax
 d85:   44 0f b6 c0             movzbl %al,%r8d
 d89:   48 8b 05 d8 12 20 00    mov    0x2012d8(%rip),%rax        # 202068 <const_launcher>
 d90:   48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
 d93:   75 09                   jne    d9e <main+0x1f4>
 d95:   48 8b 45 e8             mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rax
 d99:   48 8b 10                mov    (%rax),%rdx
 d9c:   eb 07                   jmp    da5 <main+0x1fb>
 d9e:   48 8b 15 c3 12 20 00    mov    0x2012c3(%rip),%rdx        # 202068 <const_launcher>
 da5:   48 8b 05 b4 12 20 00    mov    0x2012b4(%rip),%rax        # 202060 <const_progname>
 dac:   48 85 c0                test   %rax,%rax
 daf:   75 09                   jne    dba <main+0x210>
 db1:   48 8b 45 e8             mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rax
 db5:   48 8b 00                mov    (%rax),%rax
 db8:   eb 07                   jmp    dc1 <main+0x217>
 dba:   48 8b 05 9f 12 20 00    mov    0x20129f(%rip),%rax        # 202060 <const_progname>
 dc1:   48 8b 0d b0 12 20 00    mov    0x2012b0(%rip),%rcx        # 202078 <const_jargs>
 dc8:   48 8b 75 e8             mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rsi
 dcc:   8b 7d d0                mov    -0x30(%rbp),%edi
 dcf:   6a 00                   pushq  $0x0
 dd1:   41 51                   push   %r9
 dd3:   41 50                   push   %r8
 dd5:   6a 00                   pushq  $0x0
 dd7:   52                      push   %rdx
 dd8:   50                      push   %rax
 dd9:   48 8d 05 51 01 00 00    lea    0x151(%rip),%rax        # f31 <const_disable_argfile+0x4c>
 de0:   50                      push   %rax
 de1:   48 8d 05 4d 01 00 00    lea    0x14d(%rip),%rax        # f35 <const_disable_argfile+0x50>
 de8:   50                      push   %rax
 de9:   41 b9 00 00 00 00       mov    $0x0,%r9d
 def:   41 b8 00 00 00 00       mov    $0x0,%r8d
 df5:   ba 01 00 00 00          mov    $0x1,%edx
 dfa:   e8 51 fc ff ff          callq  a50 <JLI_Launch@plt>
 dff:   48 83 c4 40             add    $0x40,%rsp
 e03:   48 8b 4d f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rcx
 e07:   64 48 33 0c 25 28 00    xor    %fs:0x28,%rcx
 e0e:   00 00 
 e10:   74 05                   je     e17 <main+0x26d>
 e12:   e8 09 fc ff ff          callq  a20 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
 e17:   c9                      leaveq 
 e18:   c3                      retq   
 e19:   0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax)

0000000000000e20 <__libc_csu_init>:
 e20:   41 57                   push   %r15
 e22:   41 56                   push   %r14
 e24:   41 89 ff                mov    %edi,%r15d
 e27:   41 55                   push   %r13
 e29:   41 54                   push   %r12
 e2b:   4c 8d 25 e6 0e 20 00    lea    0x200ee6(%rip),%r12        # 201d18 <__frame_dummy_init_array_entry>
 e32:   55                      push   %rbp
 e33:   48 8d 2d e6 0e 20 00    lea    0x200ee6(%rip),%rbp        # 201d20 <__init_array_end>
 e3a:   53                      push   %rbx
 e3b:   49 89 f6                mov    %rsi,%r14
 e3e:   49 89 d5                mov    %rdx,%r13
 e41:   4c 29 e5                sub    %r12,%rbp
 e44:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
 e48:   48 c1 fd 03             sar    $0x3,%rbp
 e4c:   e8 5f fb ff ff          callq  9b0 <_init>
 e51:   48 85 ed                test   %rbp,%rbp
 e54:   74 20                   je     e76 <__libc_csu_init+0x56>
 e56:   31 db                   xor    %ebx,%ebx
 e58:   0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
 e5f:   00 
 e60:   4c 89 ea                mov    %r13,%rdx
 e63:   4c 89 f6                mov    %r14,%rsi
 e66:   44 89 ff                mov    %r15d,%edi
 e69:   41 ff 14 dc             callq  *(%r12,%rbx,8)
 e6d:   48 83 c3 01             add    $0x1,%rbx
 e71:   48 39 dd                cmp    %rbx,%rbp
 e74:   75 ea                   jne    e60 <__libc_csu_init+0x40>
 e76:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
 e7a:   5b                      pop    %rbx
 e7b:   5d                      pop    %rbp
 e7c:   41 5c                   pop    %r12
 e7e:   41 5d                   pop    %r13
 e80:   41 5e                   pop    %r14
 e82:   41 5f                   pop    %r15
 e84:   c3                      retq   
 e85:   90                      nop
 e86:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
 e8d:   00 00 00 

0000000000000e90 <__libc_csu_fini>:
 e90:   f3 c3                   repz retq 

Disassembly of section .fini:

0000000000000e94 <_fini>:
 e94:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
 e98:   48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
 e9c:   c3                      retq   
wxf@wxf:/home/wxf/sandboxJDK/9jdk/build/linux-x86_64-normal-server-slowdebug/jdk/bin$
```

Obviously, it is not complete. [Source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9) contains much more code than the above, like Garbage Collection.

So, how to use objdump to disassemble OpenJDK(bin/java)? I need to hack GC part in JVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java` binary is a simple launcher. There is no JVM code there. What you need is `libjvm.so`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26020872/totally-confused-with-java-exe/26025656#26025656) for details.

Answer (score 0):

The Java program links to other program files, you can use ldd to look at the shared libraries required by Java.

```
dexter@dextercd ~ % ldd /usr/bin/java
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffea42ec000)
        libjli.so => not found
        libc.so.6 => /usr/bin/../lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3002e60000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f300341a000)
```

In this case `libjli.so` probably contains more of Java's runtime code.

Comment: Actually it's in `libjvm.so`. `libjli.so` contains the common code shared by all the launchers (`java`, `javac`, `javap`, etc.). It loads `libjvm.so` and starts the JVM.

Comment: @Gilles D I am interested in GC in HotSpot. Do you think that is also in the `libjvm.so`?