# What are threads (i.e. lightweight processes) named `{java}` created for?

Tags: java, linux, jvm

I wrote a Java program that sleeps for a while:

```
package com.mycompany.app;

import java.lang.System;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("the current process's pid is " + ProcessHandle.current().pid());
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Hello World!"); // Prints the string to the console.

    }
}
```

I run the program with:

```
$ java -cp target com.mycompany.app.Main 
the current process's pid is 10172
```

I inspect the processes that Ubuntu creates to run it:

```
$ pstree -pau -l -G -s 10172
systemd,1 splash
  └─lxterminal,3194,t
      └─bash,12150
          └─java,10172 -cp target com.mycompany.app.Main
              ├─{java},10173
              ├─{java},10174
              ├─{java},10175
              ├─{java},10176
              ├─{java},10177
              ├─{java},10178
              ├─{java},10179
              ├─{java},10180
              ├─{java},10181
              ├─{java},10182
              ├─{java},10183
              ├─{java},10184
              ├─{java},10185
              ├─{java},10186
              ├─{java},10187
              ├─{java},10188
              ├─{java},10189
              └─{java},10190
```

- What are those  threads (i.e. lightweight processes) named `{java}`  created for?
- Is it possible to find out what programs  they run from shell using some commands?
- Which processes (and LWPs) are running JVM?
- Which processes (and LWPs) are running my Java program?

Comment: Can you infer anything useful from [listing all the threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1323408/3788176)

Comment: In particular, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1323419/3788176) may be useful

Comment: I believe they're all for the jvm (the part that reads bytecode and executes it as system specific code)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of these threads belong to JVM.
Run `jstack <pid>` to get the thread list.

```
"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=150.00ms elapsed=8.04s tid=0x00007f9f90011000 nid=0x107 waiting on condition  [0x00007f9f99f9f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
        at java.lang.Thread.sleep(java.base@11.0.1/Native Method)
        at java.lang.Thread.sleep(java.base@11.0.1/Thread.java:339)
        at java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.sleep(java.base@11.0.1/TimeUnit.java:446)
        at com.mycompany.app.Main.main(Main.java:10)

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 cpu=0.00ms elapsed=7.95s tid=0x00007f9f901f9000 nid=0x10e waiting on condition  [0x00007f9f6c10f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.lang.ref.Reference.waitForReferencePendingList(java.base@11.0.1/Native Method)
        at java.lang.ref.Reference.processPendingReferences(java.base@11.0.1/Reference.java:241)
        at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(java.base@11.0.1/Reference.java:213)

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=0 cpu=0.00ms elapsed=7.95s tid=0x00007f9f901fd800 nid=0x10f in Object.wait()  [0x00007f9f65fef000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@11.0.1/Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x0000000712108f80> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(java.base@11.0.1/ReferenceQueue.java:155)
        - waiting to re-lock in wait() <0x0000000712108f80> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(java.base@11.0.1/ReferenceQueue.java:176)
        at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(java.base@11.0.1/Finalizer.java:170)

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=0.00ms elapsed=7.93s tid=0x00007f9f90210000 nid=0x110 runnable  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" #5 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=40.00ms elapsed=7.93s tid=0x00007f9f90212000 nid=0x111 waiting on condition  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
   No compile task

"C1 CompilerThread0" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=40.00ms elapsed=7.93s tid=0x00007f9f90214000 nid=0x112 waiting on condition  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
   No compile task

"Sweeper thread" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=10.00ms elapsed=7.93s tid=0x00007f9f90216000 nid=0x113 runnable  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Service Thread" #9 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=0.00ms elapsed=7.90s tid=0x00007f9f902d3800 nid=0x114 runnable  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Common-Cleaner" #10 daemon prio=8 os_prio=0 cpu=0.00ms elapsed=7.89s tid=0x00007f9f902df800 nid=0x116 in Object.wait()  [0x00007f9f656ef000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(java.base@11.0.1/Native Method)
        - waiting on <0x0000000712002df0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(java.base@11.0.1/ReferenceQueue.java:155)
        - waiting to re-lock in wait() <0x0000000712002df0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
        at jdk.internal.ref.CleanerImpl.run(java.base@11.0.1/CleanerImpl.java:148)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.1/Thread.java:834)
        at jdk.internal.misc.InnocuousThread.run(java.base@11.0.1/InnocuousThread.java:134)

"Attach Listener" #11 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 cpu=0.00ms elapsed=0.21s tid=0x00007f9f44001000 nid=0x126 waiting on condition  [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"VM Thread" os_prio=0 cpu=0.00ms elapsed=7.95s tid=0x00007f9f901f1000 nid=0x10d runnable

"GC Thread#0" os_prio=0 cpu=0.00ms elapsed=8.01s tid=0x00007f9f90038800 nid=0x108 runnable

"G1 Main Marker" os_prio=0 cpu=0.00ms elapsed=8.00s tid=0x00007f9f90097800 nid=0x109 runnable

"G1 Conc#0" os_prio=0 cpu=0.00ms elapsed=8.00s tid=0x00007f9f90099800 nid=0x10a runnable

"G1 Refine#0" os_prio=0 cpu=0.00ms elapsed=8.00s tid=0x00007f9f9018d000 nid=0x10b runnable

"G1 Young RemSet Sampling" os_prio=0 cpu=0.00ms elapsed=8.00s tid=0x00007f9f9018f000 nid=0x10c runnable
"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=0 cpu=0.00ms elapsed=7.90s tid=0x00007f9f902d6000 nid=0x115 waiting on condition
```

Here `nid` is the hexadecimal ID of a thread in the OS - you may match it to the output of `pstree`.

- The first thread named `main` is the thread executing your code.
- `Reference Handler` thread is responsible for adding Weak, Soft and Phantom references discovered by Garbage Collector into their registered [ReferenceQueues](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/ReferenceQueue.html).
- `Finalizer` thread runs `finalize` method of the objects ready to be finalized.
- `Signal Dispatcher` waits for specific OS signals and handles them. In particular, it makes thread dump on `SIGQUIT`, and also initiates VM shutdown process on `SIGTERM`, `SIGINT` and `SIGHUP`.
- `CompilerThreads` perform JIT compilation of the bytecode.
- `Sweeper thread` cleans up obsolete compiled methods.
- `Service Thread` runs several background JVM tasks: detects low memory condition, cleans up StringTable and SymbolTable, sends deferred JVMTI events and GC notifications and so on.
- `Common-Cleaner` runs cleaning actions of [`java.lang.ref.Cleaner`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/Cleaner.html) instances.
- `Attach Listener` thread supports Dynamic Attach mechanism. It listens for incoming Dynamic Attach connections and executes VM commands. For example, it is used by `jstack`, `jmap` and `jcmd` utilities.
- `VM Thread` runs internal VM operations that require a [safepoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29666057/analyzing-gc-logs/29673564#29673564). The examples of such operations are deoptimization, class redifinition, biased lock revocation, thread dump, heap inspection etc.
- `G1` threads are involved in Garbage Collection.
- `VM Periodic Task Thread` is used to simulate timer interrupts.

Comment: Thanks. Which server is `jstack` a client of, when running `jstack [javaprogram-pid]`? My question is posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55670135/how-do-jsp-jinfo-jstat-jmap-and-jstack-get-information-about-local-java, and I'd appreciate if you could also consider it.

Comment: @Tim `jstack` connects to the target process using Dynamic Attach mechanism, and all the work is done by the target process itself. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35963059/3448419) and [this presentation](https://vimeo.com/233820012#t=40m18s) for details.

Comment: Thanks. Do `jps` which return info about all local java processes and `jinfo, jstat, jmap` which return info about a local java process work in the same way?

Comment: @Tim I'll answer your separate question shortly.