# How do jps, jinfo, jstat, jmap and jstack get information about local Java processes?

Tags: java, linux, process, jvm

How does `jps` get information about **all the local `java` processes**?
Does it connect to some local server process to fetch the information?

How do `jinfo, jstat, jmap`, and  `jstack` get  information about **a local `java` process**? Do they connect to some local server process(es) to fetch the information?

Is `jstatd` only used for providing remote access to local `java` processes, but not for providing local access to local `java` processes?

I am running Ubuntu. My question comes from https://stackoverflow.com/a/55669949/156458.

Comment: Why are you asking the same question twice? Why are you asking the same question twice?

Comment: My apology for your misunderstanding.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`jps` finds running Java processes by scanning through `/tmp/hsperfdata_<username>` directory. Each HotSpot-based Java process creates a file in this directory with the name equal to the process ID.

The file `/tmp/hsperfdata_<username>/<pid>` contains various counters exported by the JVM. These counters can be read by an external process. This is exactly how `jstat` works. I described jvmstat performance counters in the [JavaMagazine article](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/creating-your-own-debugging-tools).

So, `jstat` can always read counters of a local Java process, but in order to be able to monitor a remote machine, `jstatd` needs to be running.

`jmap`, `jstack` and `jinfo` use Dynamic Attach mechanism. These utilities connect to the target JVM via UNIX-domain socket and send the corresponding command to the JVM. The command is executed by the remote JVM itself. Find more about Dynamic Attach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140182/running-jmap-getting-unable-to-open-socket-file/35963059#35963059) and in [this presentation](https://vimeo.com/233820012#t=40m18s).

Comment: Do utilities always connect to target JVM via Unix-domain socket? @apangin

Comment: @MS90 In JDK 8 and earlier `jmap` and `jstack` had forced mode `-F`. In this mode they used Serviceability Agent which works quite differently. The linked answer and the presentation has more details. `jinfo` also used Serviceability Agent before JDK 9. Since JDK 9 these utilities always connect to a socket on Linux and macOS, or run remote thread on Windows.

Comment: Thank you for your kind and knowledge-shareable answer, @apangin. Keep up good work.