# Is a jps process a JVM process?

Tags: java, jvm

On Ubuntu, `man jps` says

> jps - Lists the instrumented Java Virtual Machines (JVMs) on the target system.

What does a "instrumented Java Virtual Machine" mean?

```
$ jps -v
29584 Jps -Dapplication.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64 -Xms8m -Djdk.module.main=jdk.jcmd
```

Is a jps process a JVM process, by definition?

jps is an ELF file, not a JVM bytecode program compiled from a Java program:

```
$ file /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/jps
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/jps: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/l, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=3f48c70ab711b493ee793c92c19b3a884896bb4d, stripped

$ jps -v
16462 Jps -Dapplication.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64 -Xms8m -Djdk.module.main=jdk.jcmd
```

Comment: It is an instrumented JVM. A JVM is a proces. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: What does a "instrumented Java Virtual Machine" mean? Why is a jps process a JVM process?

Comment: An instrumented JVM is one that is currently exporting JMX instrumentation endpoints. A `jps` process is an instrumented JVM because that's what it says in your quotation.

Comment: Thanks. (1) What does "exporting JMX instrumentation endpoints" mean?  (2) Can you start a non-instrumented JVM?

Answer (score 8):

> What does a "instrumented Java Virtual Machine" mean?

An instrumented JVM is a JVM that is instrumented.

However, that is a fatuous definition, and I have not been able to find a clearly documented definition of what "instrumented" really means.

In fact, it potentially applies to (at least) any HotSpot JVM since Java 5.0.  The current implementation of `jps` looks for instrumented JVMs as follows:

- If you specify a `hostid`, `jps` attempts to contact an RMI service (`jstatd`) on the host to find out about the Java processes.
- If you don't specify a `hostid`, `jps` finds Java processes by looking for `/tmp/hsperfdata_<username>` directories that are readable by the current user; see [How do jps, jinfo, jstat, jmap and jstack get information about local Java processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55670135/how-do-jps-jinfo-jstat-jmap-and-jstack-get-information-about-local-java-proce/55670479#55670479).  A JVM will create one of these directories *unless* you launch the JVM with  `-XX:-UsePerfData` or `-XX:-PerfDisableSharedMem`.  (Thanks to @apangin for this information.)

But ultimately we still have a circular (working) definition: an "instrumented JVM" is one that `jps` is able to find.

---

> Is a jps process a JVM process, by definition?

The *current* implementation of `jps` is a Java class that runs in a JVM created by a generic launcher (the `jps` executable).  However, there is no "definition" that says that is *has to be* implemented this way.

Note that since `jps` without any arguments will find itself (at least on my system) that strongly (IMO) suggests that the current implementation uses an *instrumented* JVM.

---

> jps is an ELF file, not a JVM bytecode program compiled from a Java program

That actually has nothing to do with it.  A JVM is a thing (a virtual machine) that is executing a Java program.  It is not relevant to "JVM-ness" how the program is launched, or even whether the program was represented as bytecodes at launch time.

With `jlink` (or older 3rd-party products) an ordinary Java (bytecode) program can be turned into a native executable.  On Linux, `jlink` will produce an ELF file.  Yet, when you run the ELF file, you will still have a JVM.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the commands which come with the JVM are actually implemented using Java. In this case, `jps` starts a JVM to run a class `sun.tools.jps.Jps`

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/tools/jps/Jps.java.html

Similarly `javac` actually runs `com.sun.tools.javac.Main`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/com/sun/tools/javac/Main.html