# how does jconsole/visualvm know local running java apps

Tags: java, visualvm, jconsole

When you startup jconsole or visualvm they present to you a list of "locally running java apps" that could be attached to and monitored.

How does it know which apps running locally exist?

Comment: It scan the running processes of your system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from the [VisualVM documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/jmx_connections.html) (it is described in the **When Are Explicit JMX Connections Necessary?** section and concerns local instances):

> Java VisualVM discovers running applications using the `jps` tool (Solaris, Linux, or Mac OS X or Windows), which can only discover Java applications started by  the same user as the one who starts the Java VisualVM tool.

Info about how `jps` discovers local VMs is, for example, in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55670479/4929038) SO answer. In short, it scans the `/tmp/hsperfdata_<username>` directory, where JVM instances generate info files.