# How does System.out.println work at the threading level?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, java-threads

I was investigating what system calls are made on a simple `HelloWorld` java program. With a simple `strace` I noticed that there is no `write` call, which I found suspicious:

```
...
mprotect(0x7f0bcd852000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f0bce915000, 790528, PROT_READ) = 0
getpid()                                = 27931
munmap(0x7f0bcf6ac000, 174284)          = 0
getpid()                                = 27931
mmap(NULL, 1052672, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7f0bcf5d6000
clone(child_stack=0x7f0bcf6d5fb0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7f0bcf6d69d0, tls=0x7f0bcf6d6700, child_tidptr=0x7f0bcf6d69d0) = 27932
futex(0x7f0bcf6d69d0, FUTEX_WAIT, 27932, NULLHello, World
) = 0
munmap(0x7f0bbfa6c000, 140063364)       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

So, as you can see above, with a normal `strace` call only a `futex` call is made, which is waiting on the string address.

So, I ran `strace` with the `-f` parameter to see all the threads:

```
[pid 28249] pread64(3, "\312\376\272\276\0\0\0009\0\330\n\0\2\0\3\7\0\4\f\0\5\0\6\1\0\23java/n"..., 6104, 4355323) = 6104
[pid 28249] pread64(3, "\312\376\272\276\0\0\0009\0\306\n\0\2\0\3\7\0\4\f\0\5\0\6\1\0\20java/l"..., 4455, 3263638) = 4455
[pid 28249] write(1, "Hello, World\n", 13Hello, World
) = 13
[pid 28249] pread64(3, "\312\376\272\276\0\0\0009\0(\n\0\2\0\3\7\0\4\f\0\5\0\6\1\0\25java/l"..., 999, 4425942) = 999
[pid 28249] mmap(0x7f9d35ae2000, 16384, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_NORESERVE, -1, 0) = 0x7f9d35ae2000
[pid 28249] mprotect(0x7f9d2c2e7000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE) = 0
```

Like this, I can see the `write` call as well as much more `futex` calls.

My question is, what exactly happens at the threading level when `System.out.println` is called? Does Java create a dedicated thread for printing, that is then synchronized with the main thread? Also, what do they use for synchronization that in the end makes a `futex` call.

Comment: This is not an answer, but it might be interesting: https://luckytoilet.wordpress.com/2010/05/21/how-system-out-println-really-works/

Comment: *"which is waiting on the string address"* - Not exactly. What you see in the output is that "Hello world" is printed from another thread while the primordial thread is waiting on a futex (completely unrelated to the string).

Comment: "What exactly happens at the threading level when `System.out.println()` is called?" Synchronization, "Does Java create a dedicated thread for printing, that is then synchronized with the main thread?" No.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`System.out.println` has nothing to do with threads (except that `PrintStream` methods are synchronized, but that doesn't matter in an uncontended case).

Java launcher creates a JVM in a new thread, that's why *any* Java code (not just `println`) is executed in a non-primordial thread.

Running Java code in a primordial thread used to cause many problems, see [JDK-6316197](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6316197) for details.

Comment: Ah ok, so when you write `java HelloWorld` for example, the java JVM gets the program that will be executed, does some initialization (I guess) and then launches the thread with our actual program. And if we don't manually create some other threads in the program then it will all get executed in that thread. Is this correct?

Comment: @danield No, it's [launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26025656/3448419) that creates a new thread even before initializing the JVM. JVM then performs initialization and runs the application in that new thread.

Answer (score 0):

Java's `System.out` is a `PrintStream` and one of its methods is:

```
public void println(String x) {
    synchronized (this) {
        print(x);
        newLine();
    }
}
```

There you can see the synchronization (as there is in all the other *print* methods in that class).

This is used so that we will not get garbled text if multiple threads write to System.out (or any other `PrintStream` for that matter).
At least it gets easier to control on full-string parameters, as opposed to writing single chars. Which is also possible but might cause garbled output.

I do not know about the rest, the inner workings of how the OS dependent I/O is handled, there's probably more going on. But I did not take a look at that.