# what is the difference between jre in jdk and jre 7?

Tags: java

When we install java in our machine.if we go to the java location there we can find jdk1.7.0_55 folder and jre7 folder

in jdk1.7.0_55 folder again we have jre folder

please can anyone tell me actual difference between jre folder in jdk1.7.0_55 and jre7 in java

```
java-|
     |-jdk1.7.0.55-jre
     |-jre7
```

Comment: Java Runtime Environment versus Java Developer Kit.

Comment: If it's on a linux box then jre7 is probably a symbolic link to the other

Comment: There is no difference. A JDK contains a JRE. Many of the JDK tools are written in Java themselves, and a JDK without a JRE would be formally incomplete. @mikea It isn't.

Comment: @EJP It might not be on your box but it is on mine. Or did you mean it wasn't a linux box in which case you have better psychic powers than me :)

Comment: @user3145373ツ: sry,i'm not asking difference between jdk and jre just i'm asking what is the difference between jre present in jdk folder that is present in java and jre7 present in java

Comment: my question is what is difference between jre folder in jdk1.7.0_55 and jre7 in java @uwe Plonus

Answer (score 0):

Very simplistic said:

**JDK** is the development kit for developers. it has the java 'core' (JRE) and a lot more.

**JRE** alone is just needed for the virtual machine.

JDK is overkill if you only use it to open apps/websites

Answer (score 0):

**JRE:** Java Runtime Environment. It is basically the Java Virtual Machine where your Java programs run on. It also includes browser plugins for Applet execution.

**JDK:** It's the full featured Software Development Kit for Java, including JRE, and the compilers and tools (like JavaDoc, and Java Debugger) to create and compile programs.

You can see more **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906445/what-is-the-difference-between-jdk-and-jre)**

Hope this helps.