# Why deploy a JRE and not a JDK to an application server?

Tags: java, server, diagnostics

The server JRE does not include certain diagnostic tools, like `jmap` and `jstack`. What reasons are there to deploy it to a server instead of a JDK?

Comment: This feels more like a server administration question than a programming one.

Comment: multiple good reasons can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906445/what-is-the-difference-between-jdk-and-jre

Comment: @Tom I can only see one reason in that thread: JRE's are compiled without debug information, which can improve performance at the cost of being unable to step through std lib classes with a debugger. Thank you for that, but am I missing the other "multiple" reasons?

Comment: @MikeFHay It (JRE) also requires less diskspace. Oke, mayby I was a bit to enthousiastic to state 'multiple good reasons'... Personally I also would deploy the JDK.