# When JRE is a subset of JDK, why do we have to download JRE separately in a PC?

Tags: java

When the JDK already includes JRE for the execution of code, why do I have to download JRE separately to execute my java code is the doubt that's bothering me

Comment: You don't have to download it separately. The JDK *includes* the JRE plus tools for compiling code and otherwise developing java. If all you need is the ability to run Java code, then downloading the JRE is just fine, but if you want to develop it, the JDK (Java Development Kit) is what you want.

Comment: You don't have to download JRE explicitly. It comes bundled with JDK.

Comment: on your PC obviously JRE (which may be included in JDK) is needed to run your code. Other peoples also need JRE to run your code on their computers

Comment: Seems like installing the 64-bit version of Java 8 also runs a JRE installation right afterwards... but you can actually cancel out of the JRE installation, since there will already be a version of the JRE in your java dir. The JDK installation will still complete if you cancel out at this step.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I remember this depends on your OS, browser and JDK version.

Eg. if you're using a 64-bit OS and installed a 64-bit JDK, but are using a 32-bit browser, then you might have to install a 32-bit JRE if you need Java support in the browser.

Otherwise a separate JRE installation should not be required, since the JDK installation also installs the JRE.

Comment: But during the installation of JDK, there is a separate step to specify the path for JRE; why is that?

Answer (score 1):

JRE: Java Runtime Environment. It is basically the Java Virtual Machine where your Java programs run on.

JDK: It is a group of utilities one needs to develop programs in Java including JRE, and the compilers and tools (like JavaDoc, and Java Debugger) to convert the source code into bytecode.

Refer: http://javarevisited.blogspot.de/2011/12/jre-jvm-jdk-jit-in-java-programming.html

Similar, post is there on below link as well.

[What is the difference between JDK and JRE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906445/what-is-the-difference-between-jdk-and-jre)