# Jenkins doesn't recognize Java 1.6

Tags: java, jenkins

I'm trying to configure Jenkins with Java 1.6, 1.7 and 1.8.

```
$ update-alternatives --config java
Há 3 programas que oferecem "java".
Seleção    Comando
-----------------------------------------------
*+ 1           /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.91-1.b14.el7_2.x86_64/jre/bin/java
  2           /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.101-2.6.6.1.0.1.el7_2.x86_64/jre/bin/java
  3           /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java
```

As you can see the Java installation are ok. But I can configure only Java 1.8 and 1.7 on jenkins Global Tool Configuration.

[image: jenkins can not find the installation of java 1.6]

> /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64 not look like a jdk directory

Comment: You provided a `jre` directory rather than `jdk`. You need to provide a valid `jdk` directory.

Comment: Thanks, I just copy paste the result of alternatives --config java on jenkins configuration and I did not realize this mistake. Put this comment as answer please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jenkins `JAVA_HOME` parameter in the `JDK` section expects to a valid `JDK` directory.

You provided a `JRE` directory and therefore your mistake.

Simply replace the value to the `JDK` directory of your Java 1.6 installation.

More info about `JDK` vs. `JRE` click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906445/what-is-the-difference-between-jdk-and-jre)

Answer (score 0):

You got the answer, Joao Vitorino.

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64
```

is not a jdk directory, it is a jre directory.

You can try out with(asuming you are using ubuntu)

```
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-6
```

to install jdk 1.6

refer: http://openjdk.java.net/install/