# java.io.ObjectInputStream Can't be find?

Tags: java

Error Message:

> Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.io.ObjectInputStream. Fix the build path then try building this project   Rain        Unknown Java Problem

I try to got to Properties -> **Java Build Path** -> **Add Library (Tried removing then re-adding but no luck) JRE System Library [jre 1.8.0_101]**

Any ideal on how to solve this? I am stuck, please help !

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857

Comment: Are there any other errors? What is the first error?

Comment: There are two total errors: 
                                                                                                                 1. Description Resource Path Location Type
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for java.io.ObjectInputStream. Fix the build path then try building this project Rain  Unknown Java Problem

Comment: 2. Description Resource Path Location Type
The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files Game.java /Rain/src/com/thecherno/rain line 1 Java Problem

Comment: 1. is the first error

Comment: is there any lib or project except java8 lib in your classpath? Another things that try to add java8 jdk instead of jre. Here is the explanation of difference between jre and jdk http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906445/what-is-the-difference-between-jdk-and-jre

Comment: There is not any lib or project except java8.

Comment: I tried reinstalling java8 jdk and not jre, but problem still assist.