# Netbeans does not provide an option to create a java class

Tags: java, macos, netbeans

On OSX operating system, Netbeans does not provide an option to create a java class, when I have opened `New` dialog.

On Windows operating system, this option is available:

[image: Netbeans on Windows]

But on OSX operating system, this option is missing:

[image: Netbeans on OSX]

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Upon installing Netbeans, have you selected `Java` support in installation options?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have downloaded and installed [Java Development Kit (JDK)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html). It is possible that you have only [Java Runtime Envoronment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906445/what-is-the-difference-between-jdk-and-jre) installed, but JDK is not installed on your system.

Next step, uninstall Netbeans you have already installed on your system and navigate to [Netbeans Downloads Page](https://netbeans.org/downloads/)

According to your needs, choose `Java SE`, `Java EE` or `All` option on this page and download the installer.

[image: Netbeans downloads page]

As you have downloaded the installer, launch it and make sure that Java support is included to the installation options.

[image: Java Standard Edition support included]

In case you want to customize installation options, use the `Customize` button, shown on the picture above.

Just make sure, that you have enabled Java SE (Java Standard Edition) support.

Comment: I've replicated your steps up till the installer part but there isn't any customisation button for me to click. I've also checked the plugins installed and it seems that Java is already installed, just that it doesn't come up as an option as shown above.

Comment: @KhairulHafis In this case, if it is a buggy behavior, please report this issue to the Netbeans community: https://netbeans.org/community/index.html