# Can zeppelin run with just the JRE or does it require the entire JDK?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to run Zeppelin on a pi and want to save as much space as possible. In order for Zeppelin to work can I just install java's JRE or does it require the entire JDK?

Comment: Please refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906445/what-is-the-difference-between-jdk-and-jre) to understand about JDK and JRE so that you can have answer for your problem

Comment: @TuyenNguyen  That's not necessarily helpful. OP may well know what the JDK is and is asking about Zeppelin's needs.

Comment: I didn't test but in my understanding about JDK/JRE, you don't need JRE just for running Zeppelin. It would be enough to install JRE only.

Answer (score 0):

You will need JDK (just tested with JRE and not working), also look here:
https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.9.0-SNAPSHOT/quickstart/install.html

Comment: what JRE have you used? and what error message have you got with it?