# Android Studio: No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?

Tags: java, android, maven

I am running android studio on windows and I have never worked with maven before.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) on project maven-model: Compilation failure
[ERROR] No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?
```

Comment: Well, are you running on a JRE instead of a JDK? Check your Java installation.

Comment: set `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to your JDK installation, then run your maven command again

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to compile and the Java compiler comes as part of the JDK. So check your java installation and replace the path to the JRE with path to the JDK and that should resolve the above error.

Additional details on the difference between JRE and JDK in this link:[What is the difference between JDK and JRE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906445/what-is-the-difference-between-jdk-and-jre)