# jstatd, command not found CentOS 7

Tags: java, jvm, database-performance, jvm-hotspot, cassandra-2.1

I am trying to monitor VisualGC from my workstation.
**Command:** java -version

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

So i created a policy file and tried starting jstatd like below.

**file name:** jstatd.all.policy

```
grant codebase "file:${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar" {
   permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

**Command tried:** jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=jstatd.all.policy

**error:** 
    -bash: jstatd: command not found

**command:** rpm -qa | grep java
**Output:**

```
tzdata-java-2017c-1.el7.noarch
javapackages-tools-3.4.1-11.el7.noarch
java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.151-5.b12.el7_4.x86_64
java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.151-5.b12.el7_4.x86_64
python-javapackages-3.4.1-11.el7.noarch
```

---

Also, on visualvm, Tab: Visual GC, I am seeing "Not supported for this JVM"

Comment: Are you sure you've installed JDK, not JRE?

Comment: Yes, I mentioned above the output from the command also.

Comment: The above command does not tell whether you have [JDK or JRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906445/what-is-the-difference-between-jdk-and-jre). `jstatd` is a part of JDK. "jstatd: command not found" means that you don't have JDK installed or `PATH` environment variable is not configured properly.

Comment: command: java -version, shows open jdk 1.8 (which i mentioned in first line, which is not properly formatted)

Comment: Again: `java -version` does not distringuish between JDK and JRE. The link above describes the difference. JRE is a part of OpenJDK but without tools like javac, jstatd etc. Can you show the list of openjdk packages installed on your system?

Comment: Updated the question with rpm output.

Comment: That's right - you have Java Runtime Environment installed, but not Java Development Kit. Install `java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel` package which includes jstatd.

Answer (score 9):

Note that `jstatd` in CentOS 7 is now part of the package `java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel`.

To install it:

```
yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
```