# having trouble running gradle

Tags: gradle, command, prompt

I typed in the command `gradle -q run` into the command prompt and I got the response

> "Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
>
> > Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161 contains a valid JDK installation."

I don't understand what this means.

Comment: You'll need the JDK (as opposed to the JRE). More info here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906445/what-is-the-difference-between-jdk-and-jre

Comment: I installed jdk. But the prompt is telling me that I need tools.jar

Comment: Thanks for the help. It's working now

Answer (score 1):

The error is basically saying that it can't find the JDK.

To fix the problem, you need to update/create your "JAVA_HOME" system variable to point to a valid JDK. Your problem may be that you haven't created that system variable.

[Here are some instructions](http://blogbook.hu/site/react-native-could-not-find-tools-jar/) for how to do this in Windows.