# puppetDB with Server-Jre 8?

Tags: java, puppet

We are uplifting Java in our company from JDK to Server-Jre and not sure if the PuppetDB will work with Server-Jre release 8u172. The company is determined that they only wanted Server-JRE8 and not JDK. So can I get if it is possible to run PuppetDB with Server-Jre8 and if not the reasons for why it is not!

I have checked the PuppetDB website and found this, not really helping. https://docs.puppet.com/puppetdb/2.3/#nix-server-with-jdk-17

Comment: Not sure if Puppet needs to compile Java code itself. If not, you only need a JRE. https://stackoverflow.com/q/1906445/2308683

Comment: Is your version of PuppetDB that ancient? The current documentation might be more helpful.