# tomcat scripts are not handling Java environment variables in the same manner for catalina.bat and service.bat?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8, catalina

I am using tomcat 8.5.15. version for my project and I have one question about setting up java environment variables for tomcat.

I have installed JRE on my windows machine and set the environment variable as JAVA_HOME instead of JRE_HOME.

1. catalina.bat start command works fine, though I define this variable wrong.
2. `service.bat install %servicename%` is throwing an error. says 
    **The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly.
    NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE**

But, when i say `catalina.bat debug` , it throws the same error by saying **NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE**

why catalina.bat is failing to check for java environment variable if I run `catalina.bat start` ?
How to achieve the same behavior for both of these scripts ?

Thank you,
Ras Dama.

Comment: Both errors point to the same : you need to use a JDK not  a JRE.

Answer (score 0):

No.It is not a bug. JRE by only includes the Java Runtime , it is okay to use it only if you just want to run Java application and nothing more. But to use the JVM debugger feature , you must use JDK which the location is specified by `JAVA_HOME`.

`catalina.bat start` will only run Tomcat , so JRE is enough.

`catalina.bat debug` will enable the debugger and run Tomcat , so JDK is required.

In fact, `RUNNING.txt` already explains this behaviour:

> (3.2) Set JRE_HOME or JAVA_HOME (required)
>
> These variables are used to specify location of a Java Runtime
>   Environment or of a Java Development Kit that is used to start Tomcat.
>
> The JRE_HOME variable is used to specify location of a JRE. The
>   JAVA_HOME variable is used to specify location of a JDK.
>
> Using JAVA_HOME provides access to certain additional startup options
>   that are not allowed when JRE_HOME is used.
>
> If both JRE_HOME and JAVA_HOME are specified, JRE_HOME is used.

And in the `catalina.bat` , it also mentions :

```
#   JAVA_HOME       Must point at your Java Development Kit installation.
#                   Required to run the with the "debug" argument.
#
#   JRE_HOME        Must point at your Java Runtime installation.
#                   Defaults to JAVA_HOME if empty. If JRE_HOME and JAVA_HOME
#                   are both set, JRE_HOME is used.
```

Also see : [What is the difference between JDK and JRE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906445/what-is-the-difference-between-jdk-and-jre)

---

Updated on 18-June-2018 :

> Real Problem is, if you install JRE and set JRE path as JAVA_HOME
>   instead of JRE_HOME catalina.bat is able to find the jre path and
>   starts normally. But, service.bat looks for jre folder inside
>   JAVA_HOME and fails. if you define JRE_HOME variable, service.bat also
>   works great.

It is because `catalina.bat` will call `setclasspath.bat` internally and `setclasspath.bat` try to ensure `JAVA_HOME` and `JRE_HOME` are valid and consistent. In your case , it will set `JRE_HOME` to `JAVA_HOME` , so `catalina.bat` is able to find the JRE path even you did not set `JRE_HOME`.

`service.bat` have its own checking logic for the `JAVA_HOME` / `JRE_HOME`. So , if you want to install JRE only but only set `JAVA_HOME` , try to execute `setclasspath.bat` before `catalina.bat`.

Comment: Hi Chan,
Thanks for answering. But, my question is still same
why catalina.bat is failing to check for java environment variable if I run catalina.bat start ? How to achieve the same behavior for both of these scripts ?


In mycase, I installed JRE , defined environment variable as JAVA_HOME instead of JRE_HOME.
`catalina.bat start` works fine with this.
`service.bat install tomcat8.5` throws an error . saying `NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE`

Comment: You need to install JDK . Then set JAVA_HOME to the JDK 's location. There is no way to run in debug mode if you only install JRE.

Comment: `We don't need JDK. JRE should be fine, if we set JRE_HOME environment variable.`
I believe you haven't got the scenario.
First thing is, JRE is enough to run tomcat. 
Second thing is, catalina.bat and service.bat are not having the similar behavior in identifying java.
`Real Problem is,
 if you install JRE and set JRE path as JAVA_HOME instead of JRE_HOME
catalina.bat is able to find the jre path and starts normally. But, service.bat looks for jre folder inside JAVA_HOME and fails. if you define JRE_HOME variable, service.bat also works great.`

Comment: OK. Finally understand your question. See my revised answers.