# The difference between SDK's 1.8 and JDK_1.8.0

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sdk

When I open a new directory in intelliJ and create a HelloWorld.java, it asks me to define a Project SDK, and it gives me two options

1.8 (java version "1.8.0_211")

JDK_1.8.0 (java version "1.8.0_202")

One has a bunch of contents: /library/java/jvm/jdk1.8.0_211.jdk/contents/home/jre/....

 The other has /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/contents/home/jre/...

Are they the same?

I think the two are too similar for google to return valuable results

Comment: Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906445/what-is-the-difference-between-jdk-and-jre

Comment: *"Are they the same?"* No, one is version 211, the other is version 202.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the bundled JetBrains Runtime as your project SDK, it's recommended to use your system JDK to build and run the apps you are developing.

Comment: Thank you, I was just confused because I thought both were JDK. To clarify, the one labeled 1.8 (not JDK_1.8.0) is a JRE?

Comment: JetBrains Runtime is not the same as JDK or JRE, it's something in the middle as it includes some libraries missing in the JRE (`tools.jar`), but is missing some tools present in the JDK (`javadoc`, etc).