# Program runs with jdk but not with jre

Tags: java

my program (made in Netbeans) does work fine on my PC where I have jdk-12.0.2

On my other Computer where I had the newest jre1.8.0_241 it did not run, but gave me the errormessage: A JNI Error has occured, please check your installation and try again.

I installed the newest jdk-13.0.2 and now it works.

But what could be the reason for this?
When do I need the jdk and when is the jre enough?
Or did I mess up somewhere and the jre should've done the job?

Many thanks in advance!

*my program is a GUI of a simple text game, so I used only java.awt, java.swing and java.util if this is important*

I had a look at this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906445/what-is-the-difference-between-jdk-and-jre) and I really dont understand why installing the jdk solved my issue with running the program

Comment: sorry if this is a stupid question, but could the pom.xml file have to do with this?

Comment: Ignore the difference between the JRE and the JDK for now. You built your program using version 12 of Java, and then you tried to run it using version 8 of Java, which is much older.

Comment: You might have a version conflict. Java 12 bytecode is incompatible with Java 8.

Comment: Try install jre-12.0.2

Comment: okay, now I feel really stupid.. seems pretty obvious..
But if I go on java java.com why do I get the suggestion to download version 8?
Where can I download version 12?

Comment: you can download JDK 12 from here : https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk12-archive-downloads.html

Comment: Java 8 is LTS versión and has suport up 2030.

Comment: is there a jre version 12? or just jdk?

Comment: Inside a JDK folder you can find the JRE folder for that version

Comment: @Egeo That is no longer true as of Java 9.