# IntelliJ won't recognize JDK on Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, intellij-idea, sdk

I installed `openjdk` using the command:

```
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless
```

`java -version` command correctly displays the installed package

```
openjdk 11.0.15 2022-04-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+10-Ubuntu-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.15+10-Ubuntu-0ubuntu0.22.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

However, when I open the IntelliJ IDEA environment, and want to run the first project, the environment does not detect the sdk

Should I configure something else beforehand, I haven't had much experience with Ubuntu before, for comparison in windows using the command `-java version` I get this message: completely different from what I get on ubuntu and everything works fine

```
java version "17" 2021-09-14 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17+35-LTS-2724)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17+35-LTS-2724, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because you've installed **JRE** instead of **JDK**.
see: [What is the difference between JDK and JRE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906445/what-is-the-difference-between-jdk-and-jre)

Just try `sudo apt install openjdk-17-jdk`

Comment: thanks for the answer, so it follows that I need the JDK, do I need to uninstall the JRE somehow (what I did earlier) or just run the command `sudo apt install openjdk-17-jdk` and everything will work fine?

Comment: Just install JDK. It's not the problem that you have this previously installed JRE