# How can Homebrew automatically update JAVA_HOME after it updates JDKs?

Tags: java, macos, shell, environment-variables, homebrew

I'm using macOS, when homebrew updates the JDK I have to manually update the $JAVA_HOME path in .zshrc since it uses the version number in its path, just replace the version number to a newer one like

`/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk@11/11.0.14/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home`

to

`/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk@11/11.0.16/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home`

As you can see there is just a difference in version numbers, other directory names are still the same. Is there any way to automatically update JAVA_HOME to the path that Homebrew just updated?

Comment: Sort those directories by timestamp and pick the latest? `export JAVA_HOME=find_latest_java ` (write your function)

Comment: Cool thoughts. However, typically Homebrew just removes the old one and puts the latest one under the same parent directory, namely, just one directory exists.

Comment: Well, that's even easier then - a straight find rather than a sort required. Even ```export JAVA_HOME=$(find /usr/local/Cellar -type d -name openjdk\*)```  might do it (for bash - but might also work in zsh - not 100% sure)

Comment: This question should not be closed. It's about: `software tools primarily used by programmers`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the default macOS command `java_home`:

```
% /usr/libexec/java_home -v 11
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk@11/11.0.16.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
```

And put this in your `.zshrc`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11`
```

From `man java_home`:

```
java_home - return a value for $JAVA_HOME
```

Comment: Thanks, the `man java_home` really rings a bell!

Answer (score 1):

I eventually figured out what the problem is. I found a difference between **openjdk@11** and **adoptopenjdk11** installed with Homebrew.

The situation was I actually got 3 java paths on my mac, **jre8**, **openjdk@11** and **openjdk@8**.

In my opinion, `openjdk@{xx}` is like unregistered binaries that are not bound with `java_home` (brew **formulae**), however, `adoptopenjdk{xx}` are more like registered ones(brew **cask**).

And what made this situation more complex is the **jre8** downloaded from [Download Java for macOS](https://www.java.com/en/download/) which pinned the java_home to

`/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home`

That is why I could not find any other JDK paths (other than the one I downloaded from the java official website) through executing

`$ /usr/libexec/java_home -V`

since it actually searches for and lists **Java Virtual Machines** which are included by **JRE**s.
This relates to a common confusion that new developers sometimes would have - the difference between **JDK** **JRE** and even **JVM** ([What is the difference between JDK and JRE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906445/what-is-the-difference-between-jdk-and-jre)).

So the solution is installing `adoptopenjdk{xx}` if you are not strictly sticking with `openjdk@{xx}`, it would register the path of its JRE-contained JVM to the variable `java_home` , and it's ready to go with `export` in the bash/zshell profile.

Thanks to @Ortomala Lokni and @g00se as they provide useful info that inspired me to look deeper into this.