# Java -server argument

Tags: java, arguments, command-line-arguments, jvm-arguments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Real differences between “java -server” and “java -client”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198577/real-differences-between-java-server-and-java-client)

I've seen the argument "-server" used as a command line argument for java.exe:

> java.exe -server MyClass

but no matter how hard I searched the internet I found no documentation as to what exactly it does. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198577/real-differences-between-java-server-and-java-client

Comment: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/vm/index.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> **-server**
>
> Select the Java HotSpot Server VM. On a 64-bit capable jdk only the Java HotSpot Server VM is supported so the -server option is implicit. This is subject to change in a future release.

Basically, the server VM does stuff in a different way to the client VM. It has different styles of garbage collection, and it may take longer to load up but generally has higher throughput.