# GWT compile crashes JVM

Tags: eclipse, gwt, gxt

I am trying to compile a relatively simple, client-side-only GWT 2.5.0 application under JDK 7u7.

The project runs perfectly fine in development mode. I also remember it was compiling ok on another machine a while ago. (It had GWT 2.4 and some JDK 7, and I transfered my project to GWT 2.5 by creating brand new GWT project on new machine, and copying the old sources to the new src dir. I am sure everything went fine on this stage, as "development mode" runs ok, even after cleaning project/cache).

GWT Eclipse plugin is latest (installed from update site for my Indigo, yesterday).

I was trying with/without "-localWorkers 2", and also with different memory settings ("-Xmx512m", "-Xmx2048m"). I was trying different output styles (obfuscated, detailed) and different log levels (like it could change anything :)). I even tried "-draftCompile" - no success.

Anyway, in every case, the compilation stops after a few seconds with JVM crash report, on C functions like memcpy (!) or some JVM internal functions.

JVM trace file: http://pastebin.com/KzTrQqw7
GWT log on debug level: http://pastebin.com/yQZHi4Am

Any ideas why this could be happening to me?

Comment: Interesting. Have you tried with another JDK/another machine?

Comment: I am in the middle of downloading JDK 6 to check that.

Comment: Ok, how did you know that it will go ok with jdk6u38? How do I buy you a beer over the internet?

Comment: I didn't... Drink the beer yourself and contribute to this forum and I'll be as happy as Larry :-)

Comment: We successfully compile GWT 2.5.0 project JDK 7. The project has 100+ scree/views.

Comment: Also, i am curious whether this is because of running java in mixed-mode ( from your logs ). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891017/why-does-java-running-in-server-mode-say-that-the-version-is-mixed-mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it turns out that you can compile GWT with JDK7 only sometimes (I even tried creating a new, empty, sample project, the "GreetingService" one - it was crashing as well on my configuration).

But with JDK6 it goes nice, credits to Anders R. Bystrup.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used JDK 7, but I typically increase the JVM stack size to  4M

```
-Xss4M
```