# How to interpret this output from `java -version`?

Tags: java

Running `java -version` gives us the following output, but it's unclear what version it's running. The first line seems to be v11, but the second line appears to indicate that it's running v18. What's going on here?

```
java version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.11+9-LTS-194)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.11+9-LTS-194, mixed mode)
```

Comment: It's JDK 11. You can ignore the VM version

Comment: First line: `java version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20 LTS` is the JDK version installed on your machine. `18.9` is the JRE version.

Comment: Thanks! What does the 2nd line mean?

Comment: It's what the JDK calls "vendor version". They pretty much used it for Java 10 and 11 and realised it was useless. As per [JDK-8216383](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8216383) "It no longer serves any useful purpose".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This `java -version` command was executed by **Java 11** (not 18).

[Documentation for the `-version` flag](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#BGBBDHEI) suggests that the complete reference for `java -version`'s output lives in Appendix A of the [JSR-56 specification](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.296.4556&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (PDF).

For your output above:

```
// Java major version 11, minor version 0, patch version 11, release date 20th Apr 2021, Long-Term-Support (LTS) version
java version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20 LTS

// JRE major version 18, minor version 9, exact build number
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.11+9-LTS-194)

// JVM major version 18, minor version 9, exact build number
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.11+9-LTS-194, mixed mode)
```

Exact build numbers above are formatted as follows (thanks Anon: ["`+` means build"](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/11-0-11-relnotes.html#maincontent)):

```
<major>.<minor>.<patch>+<build>
```

Making some edits to the text in the flag documentation, your exact build numbers on lines 2 and 3 of your original output mean:

> the class or JAR file requires a version that is not less than 11.0.11+9

As per [JDK-8216383](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8216383), it seems line 2 of your original output ("vendor version") serves no purpose any more (thanks @Michael!).

For a definition of "mixed mode", see [Why does Java , running in -server mode, say that the version is "mixed-mode"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891017/why-does-java-running-in-server-mode-say-that-the-version-is-mixed-mode)

For more on the version discrepancy you're observing, see: [Why is java -version returning a different version to the one defined in JAVA_HOME?](https://superuser.com/questions/237737/why-is-java-version-returning-a-different-version-to-the-one-defined-in-java-ho)

Comment: @user16320675 this is what "`11.0.11+`" means, in the version output from OP, according to the `-version` flag's documentation. I think we are saying the same thing: "not less than 11" means the same as "any version of Java 11 (or later)" ;)

Comment: Ah, I see! I was under the impression that the `+` indicated "the preceding version ID onwards", but it seems that it doesn't. I've amended my answer above to reflect this.