# Should I run JMH benchmarks with '-server' option

Tags: java, benchmarking, jmh

I am using [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/), an OpenJDK microbenchmark tool. The build process creates `microbenchmarks.jar` that I invoke with `java -jar` and passing jar name and JMH arguments.

I wonder should we run the benchmarks with `-server` option and why?

In other words, should I run my benchmark with:

```
java -server -jar microbenchmarks.jar ...(jmh args)
```

Comment: Please elaborate on the question, it's not clear what you are asking. Should you use `-server` for benchmarking? Should you pass `-server` to JMH launcher?

Comment: should I pass '-server' to JVM that runs the microbenchmarks.jar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, it depends on what you are trying to measure. In most cases, the default JVM mode on the machine is what you are after to replicate the same conditions which the ordinary Java application will encounter.

Hence, we usually don't add `-server` to benchmark runs, because on most machines the ergonomics itself implicitly selects it, see [Server Class Machine Detection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/server-class.html).

Answer (score 3):

That entirely depends on what you *want* to benchmark - you should use that option if you want to measure how the system would behave when running server oriented workloads, using server JVM characteristics

see also - [What is JVM -server parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272674/what-is-jvm-server-parameter) , indicating that the `-server` switch also performs better JITting.

Comment: I think the same, and all previous microbenchmark tools say something similar; I just couldn't found any such example on JMH site - so I start to think if there is a reason for that ;) Lets see what @Aleksey  Shipilev has to say :)