# Java execution from commandline is slower than in IntelliJ

Tags: java, command-line, intellij-idea

I have written a simple factorial program, with arbitrary precision:

```
public class Fac {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int stop = 100000;

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        BigInteger integer = new BigInteger("1");
        for(int i = 2; i <= stop; i++){
            integer = integer.multiply(new BigInteger(i +""));
        }

        System.out.println("It took: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms");
        //System.out.println(integer);
    }
}
```

When i run it in IntelliJ:

```
It took: 5392ms
```

When i run it in commandline:

```
It took: 17919ms
```

The commandline is run by:

```
javac Fac.java
java Fac
```

I know this is not the best way to measure time but the gap is soo huge that it does not matter.
Why is the performence that different?

Other people has noticed similar difference, however, as far as i can tell, their conclusions seem unrelated to my situation.

[Why is my application running faster in IntelliJ compared to command-line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111127/why-is-my-application-running-faster-in-intellij-compared-to-command-line#answers-header)

http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Why-does-IntelliJ-IDEA-runs-faster-than-Windows-command-line-td3894823.html

Comment: Are both IntelliJ and cmd line running on same JRE?

Comment: Does IntelliJ have it's own compiler like Eclipse?

Comment: @TheLostMind Almost. IntelliJ uses the 1.8.0_11 SDK, which ships with a jre to my understanding. The commandline uses 1.8.0_25 jre, but the compiler is still 1.8.0_11.

Comment: @Bjerrum - Oh. I don't use IntelliJ. Anyways I guess *Vikingsteve*  has already answered your question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you are launching the jvm to run your program with different classpath, arguments, etc.

If you run the program in IntelliJ, you will see the first line of the `Run` window something like *"C:\Program ..."*

Click on it to expand it, and you will see all the arguments used when intellij runs your program (I am splitting an example over several lines here).

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin\java"
-Didea.launcher.port=7532
 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.0.3\bin"
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\jre\lib\charsets.jar;...etc..."
Fac
```

If you duplicate the exact same arguments (using the exact same jvm) then you will likely see similar performance when you run your application manually.

Your system settings for `PATH`, `JAVA_HOME` and `CLASSPATH` are used by default for launching your program if you don't specify them fully.

Comment: Thank you. Would upvote if i could. Where can i gain insight into this magic?

Comment: Found a link here: http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Environment_Variables.html