# What is the difference between the Java Client VM and the Server VM?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Real differences between "java -server" and "java -client"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198577/real-differences-between-java-server-and-java-client)

what are the technical differences between starting a java program with -server and with -client flag?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

from [Frequently Asked Questions About the Java HotSpot VM](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#compiler_types) :

> These two systems are different binaries. They are essentially two
>   different compilers (JITs)interfacing to the same runtime system. The
>   client system is optimal for applications which need fast startup
>   times or small footprints, the server system is optimal for
>   applications where the overall performance is most important. In
>   general the client system is better suited for interactive
>   applications such as GUIs. Some of the other differences include the
>   compilation policy,heap defaults, and inlining policy.

Answer (score 2):

One difference that I know of is related to `JIT (Just In Time)` compilation where JVM at **runtime** identifies hotspots in the code and based on that converts bytecodes into highly optimized native code.

With `-client` flag, the amount of JIT'ing performed is lesser than performed with `-server` flag. This is because clients are interactive apps that generally require low start-up times, and JIT'ing causes some start-up delays. You can read more about JIT here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation

Also, I think (not very sure) that there would be some difference in Garbage Collection defaults selected with the change in these flags.