# java compile- versus run- time computation

Tags: java, enums, runtime

I'm trying to understand compile versus run-time computation in java. I have the following 
enum

```
public enum SightSensor{

  NORTH (new MapLocation[]{new MapLocation(0,1), 
                         new MapLocation(0,2),
                         new MapLocation(0,3)}),
  SOUTH (new MapLocation[]{new MapLocation(0,-1), 
                        new MapLocation(0,-2),
                        new MapLocation(0,-3)});

  private final MapLocation[] locs;

  SightSensor(MapLocation[] locs){
    this.locs = locs;
  }

  public static MapLocation[] getLocs(Direction dir){
    if (dir == Direction.NORTH)
      return NORTH.locs;
    if (dir == Direction.SOUTH)
      return SOUTH.locs;
  }
};
```

In words, I want to define a constant mapping between a Direction and an array of 
MapLocations. (Perhaps this is the wrong way to do this? I'm new to Java.) Now, if I 
write

```
MapLocation[] locs = SightSensor.getLocs(Direction.SOUTH_WEST);
```

inside a loop in the code, I find that there is a cost overhead the first time the code
is called, implying to me it is somehow being computed/instantiated at run time. If instead
I just directly code

```
MapLocation[] locs = new MapLocation[]{new MapLocation(0,1),
                           new MapLocation(0,2),
                           new MapLocation(0,3)};
```

there is no cost overhead. I don't understand the difference. Does the compiler do some
weird sort of just-in-time computation?

Comment: Can you explain how you are measuring the cost overhead?

Comment: Also, your example does not compile; you need some kind of else statement in `getLocs`, because now there are paths without a return value (when `dir` is neither NORTH nor SOUTH)

Comment: Nail, sorry about that, attempted to simplify the code. Measuring in bytecode.

Comment: Ok. But...I assumed the cost overhead was time, not space? :-) How are you relating bytecode size to first/second time running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the cost you're seeing is the class-loading cost: the first time the code accesses a class, the class-loader loads its binary (.class file) into memory. This is a one time cost that for most practical purposes is negligible.

Moreover:

> Now, if I write ... inside a loop in the code, I find that there is a cost overhead the first time the code is called,

How did you measure this cost? It is nearly impossible to measure the time cost of a single operation. You can measure the time needed to carry out xM passes thru a loop and then you can divide to get the amortized cost. However, measuring a single operation is difficult: you may be getting a Garbage Collection cycle, a thread-related context switch, etc. Moreover, the JIT (Just In Time) Compiler does not kick the first time a statement is executed, so measuring a single operation will usually give you a much higher cost than amortized cost over N operations.

FWIW, I would write `getLocs()` as follows:

```
public static MapLocation[] getLocs(Direction dir) {
  return valueOf(dir.name()).locs;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use replace the SightSensor enum with a variable of type EnumMap:

```
EnumMap<Direction, MapLocation[]> map = new EnumMap(Direction.class);
map.put(Direction.NORTH, new MapLocation[] {  new MapLocation(0, 1), 
                                              new MapLocation(0, 2),
                                              new MapLocation(0, 3) });
map.put(Direction.NORTH, new MapLocation[] {  new MapLocation(0, -1), 
                                              new MapLocation(0, -2),
                                              new MapLocation(0, -3) });
```

Then, `getLocs()` calls simply become `map.get(dir)`

Comment: I'm actually measuring the cost in bytecode, so timing is not an issue but the manner of the compilation is.

Comment: Itay, Thanks for the answer. It seems EnumMap is the right choice for this task.

Answer (score 2):

> Does the compiler do some weird sort of just-in-time computation?

Yes, the Java run-time does use statistics to optimize the code as it runs:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstat.html

Nothing weird about it.

This might be pertinent as well:

[Real differences between "java -server" and "java -client"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198577/real-differences-between-java-server-and-java-client)

Personally, I think you should write the code to be as easy to read as possible and not worry about optimization.  The speedup probably isn't significant.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm coming from c++ so I'm not cognizant of these details yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer, but a tip: Make `getLocs` non-static and just return the `locs` of the current enum:

```
public MapLocation[] getLocs(){
    return locs;
}
```

Instead of `SightSensor.getLocs(someDir)` you then call `someDir.getLocs()`.

This way you avoid having to enumerate all members of the enum.