# Change Default Java VM to Client

Tags: java, jvm, client, fedora

I installed Oracle's Java on Fedora 17, and I noticed that when using the command `java -version` it returns this

```
java version "1.7.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_05-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.1-b03, mixed mode)
```

Java seems to run the -server option by default. The help text came up as

```
-server   to select the "server" VM
              The default VM is server,
              because you are running on a server-class machine.
```

Is there any way to change the default to client?

Comment: Also, the question is _why_ you want to use the client vm?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen "change the default" means to change what you get if you don't specify one.

Comment: @Fredrik yes.  Question is why it is necessary or desirable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default setting is defined in the file **jvm.cfg**. A content like

```
-client KNOWN
-server KNOWN
```

defines the client as the default.

```
-server KNOWN
-client KNOWN
```

sets the server as the default.

Source: [www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0566.html](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0566.html)

#### jvm.cfg location

Unknown Mac OS X version:

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jvm.cfg`

Mac OS X version 10.9 without installing JDK:

`/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jvm.cfg`

Mac OS X version 10.9 with installed JDK version 1.8.0_u92:

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jvm.cfg`

---

<sup>You can find your `jvm.cfg` from the command line (Terminal.app) using the command `$ locate /jvm.cfg`. You might need to update your locate database first, using the command: `$ sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb`</sup>

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/vm/server-class.html):

> Note: For J2SE 5.0, the definition of a server-class machine is one
>   with at least 2 CPUs and at least 2GB of physical memory.

So there doesn't seem any way to alter the server-class machine detection technique, I'm guessing you will have to stick to passing the `-client` VM argument if you need it on your machine.

Also worth noting is that this page is for Java 5, so things might be different with Java 6 and higher.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Java 5, you can specify this as an option to the JVM:

- the `-client` option will make the VM start in client mode. In this mode, the start-up will be much faster.
- the `-server` option will make the VM start in server mode. The start-up will be slower, but in the long run, it will execute faster.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/198577/995822) for more details about the differences about the 2 modes.

If you do not specify these options, the VM will check to see if you have at least 2 CPUs and at least 2 GB RAM. If you do, then it will start in server mode.

You can see the tables about how these decisions are made:

- [here for Java 5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/vm/server-class.html)
- [here for Java 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/vm/server-class.html) and
- [here for Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/server-class.html)

FYI: they are all the same.