# java hotspot from server to client

Tags: java, client, server

Java -version shows hotspot as server. I want to change this to client.

how to change java hotspot from server to client in windows ?

My jvm.cfg file looks like:
-client KNOWN
-server KNOWN
-hotspot ALIASED_TO -client
-classic WARN
-native ERROR
-green ERROR

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to :[Change Default Java VM to Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175624/change-default-java-vm-to-client)

Make sure you reverse the default order in jvm.cfg file.
-client KNOWN
-server KNOWN
such that client is picked as default.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a 64bit supported JVM -client will be ignored and JVM will always run in server mode