# What's Tiered Compilation in Java 7?

Tags: java, jvm, java-7

Please help me knowing tiered compilation in deeper, which was a new feature in Java SE 7.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This question is too vague to attract a suitable answer. Work out what it is you don't understand about tiered compilation, and consider asking one or more specific questions about the topic.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html)

> Tiered Compilation
>
> Tiered compilation, introduced in Java SE 7, brings client startup
>   speeds to the server VM. Normally, a server VM uses the interpreter to
>   collect profiling information about methods that is fed into the
>   compiler. In the tiered scheme, in addition to the interpreter, the
>   client compiler is used to generate compiled versions of methods that
>   collect profiling information about themselves. Since the compiled
>   code is substantially faster than the interpreter, the program
>   executes with greater performance during the profiling phase. In many
>   cases, a startup that is even faster than with the client VM can be
>   achieved because the final code produced by the server compiler may be
>   already available during the early stages of application
>   initialization. The tiered scheme can also achieve better peak
>   performance than a regular server VM because the faster profiling
>   phase allows a longer period of profiling, which may yield better
>   optimization.

Comment: Thanks for that. Understanding that I'm a greenhorn, can u please let me know the following.
1. Does the 'client' JIT compiler, and the 'server' JIT compiler lie in the server itself? Why they are called client and server? I'm puzzled. Help me.

Comment: "client" and "server" here refer to the respective hotspot vm which are tuned differently. Some details here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198577/real-differences-between-java-server-and-java-client