# What are major difference of running my application in a Server JRE vs JRE?

Tags: java, jvm

I have seen in oracle website there are two types jre download.

What are the differences of running my application in server JRE vs JRE and are there any limitations imposed upon the application of choosing one runtime environment over another?

Comment: I guess reading the text on that page that tells you exactly what the difference is was out of the question?

Comment: According to the Oracle [website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/server-jre7-downloads-1931105.html) it comes with server tools but no browser integration.

Comment: Most systems have the server JRE these days, except 32-bit Windows like Windows XP.

Comment: Additional/relevant info can be found in [Real differences between "java -server" and "java -client"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198577/real-differences-between-java-server-and-java-client)

Comment: I find it VERY strange for this question to be closed because it's off-topic and down-voted too. While (Richard Sitze), thankfully, referred to the same exact question, with around 150 up-votes for the question, a bit more than that for the accepted answer !

Comment: I agree with the abusive close, as it's specifically "involving a tool used primarily for programming" : java
Now this topic talk about "Server JRE" which has been introduced from Java 1.7.0 but @RichardSitze give a link about start options "-client" or "-server" which may be a close subject but not specifically this one

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Read the [documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/server-jre7-downloads-1931105.html):

> The Server JRE is a runtime environment specifically targeted for deploying Java in server environments and it is available for 64-bit Linux, Solaris and Windows platforms.
>
> **The Server JRE includes tools for JVM monitoring and tools commonly required for server applications, but does not include browser integration (the Java plug-in).**

Comment: The documentation does not say that the included tools are the only differences. In particular it says nothing about whether there are differences similar to the differences between hava -client vs java -server.

Answer (score 5):

Server JRE includes monitoring tools and JRE( for end user) doesn't.