# how to handle issue regarding Missing "server" JVM at "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\server\jvm.dll"

Tags: java, atlassian-fisheye

I've seen some answers to this question but it doesn't seem to be working for me. I have "client" folder inside "bin" which has such a file (in Program Files x86) but when I set my JAVA_HOME variable to this java folder, it shows this error whenever I try to start the service (I'm trying to run Atlassian Fisheye as service). I tried copying the contents of the "client" folder and create a "server" folder but then the error is changed

`Error occurred during initialization of VM,
Could not reserve enough space for object heap,
Could not create the Java Virtual Machine,
A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.`

if I install 64 bit version of Java as well, there I have this "server" folder, I tried copying that folder but still no use. if I change my JAVA_HOME path to that 64 bit java folder, the service is started successfully, (or so it seems) but I can't access Fisheye and there's a warning:

`WARNING - Unable to load the Wrapper's native library 'wrapper.dll'. The file is located on the path at the following location but could not be loaded: C:\installs\service\fisheye28\wrapper\lib\wrapper.dll. Please verify that the file is readable by the current user and that the file has not been corrupted in any way. System signals will not be handled correctly.`

according to [this guide](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/FISHEYE/Running+FishEye+as+a+Windows+service#RunningFishEyeasaWindowsservice-environvariables) here, it happens if we use 64 bit java, and we have to use 32 bit even if it's a 64 bit machine. so, I'm stuck in between these issues. the "server" error is gone if I use 64 bit version but then this warning is there and I can't access Fisheye. if I use 32 bit, the "server: folder is not found, and even if i copy the files and create a folder, the service still doesn't run.

Comment: _tried copying the contents of the "client" folder and create a "server" folder but then the error is changed _.  HM. copying files across jre folders is not a good idea.

Comment: I guess so, I was wondering why people are suggesting something like that so I tried that as well.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is already quite old. But I will try to explain what worked for me:

> I tried copying the contents of the "client" folder and create a
>   "server" folder but then the error is changed

That trick was voted as useful by many users in a similar question. However you can not use a Java Client as a Java Server.

In this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/198651/7597328) you can see the reason. Basically:

- The Server VM has been specially tuned to maximize peak operating
  speed.
- The Server VM contains an advanced adaptive compiler that supports
  many of the same types of optimizations performed by optimizing C++
  compilers, as well as some optimizations that cannot be done by
  traditional compilers.

The solution I found was to download a Java Server from:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/server-jre7-downloads-1931105.html

Then I added the server folder to ...\Java\jre7\bin\

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK JAVA_HOME should point to the installation-directory of the jre, not to the folder containing the jvm.dll.

So try setting JAVA_HOME to the parent-directory of the bin-folder...

Comment: Let me clarify my situation a little more, my JAVA_HOME variable points to "C:\Progra~2\Java\jre7" which means it's currently looking into x86 Program Files folder, this is the parent directory, I'm not pointing it to the folder containing jvm.dll. Since I can't use 64 bit version of Java, I need to get this service running with 32 bit version. Right now, JAVA_HOME points to 32 bit Java directory, and since there's no server folder, the service cannot be started. Can you help me set that up?