# Hazelcast demo run.sh file

Tags: hazelcast

Hi I am new to Hazelcast

What does this line in the run.sh file :
    java -server -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true  mean ?

Comment: Maybe you can gave a look at the documentation. If something is still not clear, please update the question with the information about your research so that others can help you exactly.

Comment: Did you try https://www.google.no/search?q=java.net.preferIPv4Stack ?

Answer (score 1):

For the -server setting see:

[Real differences between "java -server" and "java -client"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198577/real-differences-between-java-server-and-java-client)

And -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true indicates that is should try to use ipv4 instead of ipv6.