# JAVA_OPTS set in catalina.sh not working for TOMCAT private instance

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu, catalina, java-opts

I have placed JVM options via JAVA_OPTS in catalina.sh in the catalina base. However, the system doesn't pick those options--I am trying to pass profiling information to set paths for project properties and logging files. I have to set the options in setenv.sh in the private instance's bin. Even the echo command that I put in catalina.sh to view the JAVA_OPTS doesn't get printed-defaults like CATALINA_BASE,etc. do get printed. Is catalina.sh even being processed?

At the end of the day, my system works fine with setenv.sh. I am curious as to why JAVA_OPTS are not being picked up from catalina.sh.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with TOMCAT 7 installed and JDK 1.7.

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

You are not supposed to edit the catalina.sh file - it states so in that file. Instead, to **set** your **env**ironmental variables, create a **setenv.sh** file in the same directory where catalina.sh is (called CATALINA_BASE/bin) and write your code in it.

I had to set the `JAVA_OPTS` variable myself, and I created the `bin/setenv.sh` file, set it to executable `chmod +x bin/setenv.sh` and wrote in it:

`JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xms128m -Xmx512m -server"`

which set my initial allocated memory to 128 and max memory to 512 MB. And it was working.

Comment: you did't tell what the "-server" is doing.

Comment: @nikk http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198577/real-differences-between-java-server-and-java-client

Answer (score 2):

please edit: `/etc/default/tomcat7` or `/etc/default/{user_who_runs_tomcat}`

e.g.:

```
*JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx2G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -server -XX:MaxPermSize=384m"*
```

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more? As to why catalina.sh settings are not working?

Answer (score 2):

`catalina.sh` has a lot of conditionals - it happened to me more than once that I edited the wrong position, or one that was overwritten later in that file. `setenv.sh` works fine, and that's exactly what it's there for: Imagine you're installing a tomcat update - this will overwrite your `catalina.sh`. However, tomcat never comes with `setenv.sh`, thus it won't overwrite your changes.

Further, you might want to define `CATALINA_OPTS` instead of `JAVA_OPTS`: Those are the options that are used to start tomcat. If part of your configuration is `JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx16G -Xms16G"`, you'd allocate 16G heap space when you try to shut down tomcat: The shutdown process spawns a JVM with the `JAVA_OPTS` parameters as well. Only the startup process spawns with the `CATALINA_OPTS` environment (in addition to `JAVA_OPTS`), thus that's most likely what you want to configure/tune, otherwise you risk not being able to stop tomcat due to ridiculous memory requirements of shutdown.sh.