# Why Android Studio, Intellij use JVM Server instead Client as default

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, ide

It is just a curious question. Why Android Studio, Intellij use Server mode instead Client as default. Should I switch to client mode to improve AS's startup time?
[image: Android Studio]

[Real differences between "java -server" and "java -client"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198577/real-differences-between-java-server-and-java-client)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server JVM performs much deeper optimizations for the code. If you start and quit Android Studio hundreds of times each day, then switching to the client JVM may actually give you better performance. Most people don't do that, and are more concerned about better performance of the IDE in the long run than about startup time. Therefore, the server VM is used by default.