# Control Java maximum Heap size in Centos 7

Tags: java, jvm, heap-memory

I need to minimize the JVM MaxHeapSize. My program keeps freezing on executing. I am using Centos 7. My JVM MaxHeapSize=2G
When applying the following command:

```
java -Xmx1024m
```

I get this error:

```
 Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
            (to execute a class)    or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
            (to execute a jar file) where options include:
     -d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
     -d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
     -server       to select the "server" VM
                   The default VM is server,
                   because you are running on a server-class machine.
```

How to change jvm to a client, and how to avoid this error. With many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error simply says that you didn't specify which class to execute. `-Xmx` is a option you may specify when starting the process. `java -Xmx1024m my.progs.Main` will work.

Even if there is an option named `-client` it will have no effect. As [Real differences between "java -server" and "java -client"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198577/real-differences-between-java-server-and-java-client) states this option is ignored on 64-bit systems.

Comment: Thanks blafasel, applying the above command results "Error: Could not find or load main class my.progs.Main"