# "Client" Java Virtual Machine with jsvc

Tags: java, jsvc, apache-commons-daemon

`jsvc` has a `-client` option but it isn't available on my system:

```
/usr/bin/jsvc -help ...
...
    -jvm <JVM name>
        use a specific Java Virtual Machine. Available JVMs:
            'server'
    -client
        use a client Java Virtual Machine.
    -server
        use a server Java Virtual Machine.
...
```

This seem to boil down to having library files in directory `lib/client` under `JAVA_HOME` -- but all I have is `lib/server`.

This directory does not exist on Arch Linux ARM aarch64 or macOS. Is that some separate install, or is jsvc simply wrong about the existence of such a VM in that place?

Comment: It was an [ancient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/198651/2970947) option that (when it did anything) was impactful on primarily 32-bit platforms (machines with less than 2 GB of RAM).

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/198651/421195 `Because on the 64-bit versions of JDK the -client option is ignored for many years. – 
G. Demecki Mar 16, 2016`

Comment: I guess my second theory was correct :-) Ty.

Answer (score 0):

This is a lab box I haven't updated for awhile ... but it looks like recent JREs  only have the "server" option:

```
C:\> java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)

c:\>java -help
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
    -server       to select the "server" VM
                  The default VM is server.
```

Also:

```
c:\Program Files\java\jdk-11.0.1>tree lib
Folder PATH listing for volume OS
Volume serial number is 00000051 4C32:5A1F
C:\PROGRAM FILES\JAVA\JDK-11.0.1\LIB
├───jfr
├───security
└───server
  <= Look Ma!  No "client"!
```